# Subset rows corresponding to max value by group using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, greatest-n-per-group

Assume I have a `data.table` containing some baseball players:

```
library(plyr)
library(data.table)

bdt <- as.data.table(baseball)
```

For each group (given by player 'id'), I want to select rows corresponding to the maximum number of games 'g'. This is straightforward in `plyr`:

```
ddply(baseball, "id", subset, g == max(g))
```

What's the equivalent code for `data.table`?

I tried:

```
setkey(bdt, "id") 
bdt[g == max(g)]  # only one row
bdt[g == max(g), by = id]  # Error: 'by' or 'keyby' is supplied but not j
bdt[, .SD[g == max(g)]] # only one row
```

This works:

```
bdt[, .SD[g == max(g)], by = id]
```

But it's is only 30% faster than `plyr`, suggesting it's probably not idiomatic.

Comment: Wow, that is slow, but if you use "year" in place of ".SD"... I'm getting .01, 1.58, 2.39 user time for year, .SD, plyr, respectively.

Comment: @Frank but I want the whole data frame, not just the year. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Here's the fast `data.table` way:

```
bdt[bdt[, .I[g == max(g)], by = id]$V1]
```

This avoids constructing `.SD`, which is the bottleneck in your expressions.

**edit:** Actually, the main reason the OP is slow is not just that it has `.SD` in it, but the fact that it uses it in a particular way - by calling `[.data.table`, which at the moment has a huge overhead, so running it in a loop (when one does a `by`) accumulates a very large penalty.

Comment: +1 I'm betting that Hadley wants to do this somewhat programmatically, in which case he'd want to use this syntax, `bdt[bdt[, .I[g == max(g)], by = id][,V1]]` right?

Comment: @joran I'm constructing the call manually, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: Eventually the original approach will be optimized. See [FR 2330](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2330&group_id=240&atid=978) Optimize `.SD[i]` query to keep the elegance but make it faster unchanged.

Comment: That issue link since moved from R-Forge to GitHub here [#613](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/613)

Comment: If I add `verbose = TRUE` to the inner frame, I see `GForce FALSE`, yet it's still faster than something like `bdt[bdt[, .(g=max(g)), by=id], on=c("id","g")]`, though I don't know if that would always be the case.