# Subsetting a dataframe by the amount of repetition

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
neu <- data.frame(test1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14), 
                  test2 = c("a","b","a","b","c","c","a","c","c","d","d","f","f","f"))
neu
   test1 test2
1      1     a
2      2     b
3      3     a
4      4     b
5      5     c
6      6     c
7      7     a
8      8     c
9      9     c
10    10     d
11    11     d
12    12     f
13    13     f
14    14     f
```

and I would like to select only those values where the level of the factor `test2` appears more than let's say three times, what would be the fastest way?

Thanks very much, didn't really find the right answer in the previous questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the rows using:

```
z <- table(neu$test2)[table(neu$test2) >= 3] # repeats greater than or equal to 3 times
```

Or:

```
z <- names(which(table(neu$test2)>=3))
```

Then subset with:

```
subset(neu, test2 %in% names(z))
```

Or:

```
neu[neu$test2 %in% names(z),]
```

Comment: Why use `as.list`? Why two `table(.)`? And it's better not to use `subset`.

Comment: See alternative strategies above.

Comment: @Arun, do you mind explaining a little or linking to a reason for your suggestion not to use ``subset``. The thing about ``subset`` is that it is intuitively named, so it's more natural to think "I'm going to subset that" rather than, say, "I'm going to use ``%in%``" or "I'm going to ``which`` it ...

Comment: @PatrickT `subset` uses non-standard evaluation, so it can produce unexpected results. For example, if you use it inside a function, it will typically not work right or at all. Best advice is to use `[` for all extraction.

Comment: @PatrickT, at the time I was probably influenced by [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset). While there are some valid points there, I don't see a reason not to use, as long as you know what you're doing. I tend to avoid suggesting "never use this/that" these days.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Arun. Sounds scary! Good question/answer you linked to.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way:

```
 with(neu, neu[ave(seq(test2), test2, FUN=length) > 3, ])

#   test1 test2
# 5     5     c
# 6     6     c
# 8     8     c
# 9     9     c
```

Comment: +1 this is by far the best base solution to me.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `count` from the `plyr` package to perform the counting:

```
library(plyr)
count_result = count(neu, "test2")
matching = with(count_result, test2[freq > 3])
with(neu, test1[test2 %in% matching])
[1] 5 6 8 9
```

Answer (score 2):

The (better scaling) `data.table` way:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(neu)

dt[dt[, .I[.N >= 3], by = test2]$V1]
```

Note: hopefully, in the future, the following simpler syntax will be the fast way of doing this:

```
dt[, .SD[.N >= 3], by = test2]
```

(c.f. [Subset by group with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table/16574176))