# Reformat repeating list in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dateset, df:

```
  state      id     year     yes
  ga         1      2020     10%
  ca         2      2020     10%
  va         1      2020     20%
  ga         1      2001     10%
  ca         2      2001     20%
  va         1      2001     10%
```

I wish for the ouput to look like this:

```
  state      id     year     yes
  ga         1      2001     10%
  ga         1      2020     10%
  ca         2      2001     20%
  ca         2      2020     10%
  va         1      2001     10%
  va         1      2020     20%
```

dput:

```
structure(list(state = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("ca", 
"ga", "va"), class = "factor"), id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L), yes = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("10%", "20%"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, 
-6L))
```

This is what I have tried

```
library(dplyr)
df1<-df %>% group_by(state)
```

Comment: You didn't explain in words what you need. You just want to order the data? Why is this the order you need?

Comment: Hey, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839096/rearrange-a-data-frame-by-sorting-a-column-within-groups.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rearrange a data frame by sorting a column within groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839096/rearrange-a-data-frame-by-sorting-a-column-within-groups)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `arrange` the data based on it's occurrence we can use `match` and `unique`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(match(state, unique(state)), year)

#  state id year yes
#1    ga  1 2001 10%
#2    ga  1 2020 10%
#3    ca  2 2001 20%
#4    ca  2 2020 10%
#5    va  1 2001 10%
#6    va  1 2020 20%
```

---

In base R, we can use `order` :

```
df[with(df, order(match(state, unique(state)), year)), ]
```

Comment: Ok this worked. Let me vote this in a few min

Answer (score 1):

We can use `factor`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(factor(state, levels = unique(state)), year)
#  state id year yes
#1    ga  1 2001 10%
#2    ga  1 2020 10%
#3    ca  2 2001 20%
#4    ca  2 2020 10%
#5    va  1 2001 10%
#6    va  1 2020 20%
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df[order(with(df, factor(state, levels = unique(state)), year)),]
```