# Extract row corresponding to minimum value of a variable by group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, aggregate

I wish to (1) group data by one variable (`State`), (2) within each group find the row of minimum value of another variable (`Employees`), and (3) extract the entire row.

(1) and (2) are easy one-liners, and I feel like (3) should be too, but I can't get it.

Here is a sample data set:

```
> data
  State Company Employees
1    AK       A        82
2    AK       B       104
3    AK       C        37
4    AK       D        24
5    RI       E        19
6    RI       F       118
7    RI       G        88
8    RI       H        42

data <- structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L), .Label = c("AK", "RI"), class = "factor"), Company = structure(1:8, .Label = c("A", 
        "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), class = "factor"), Employees = c(82L, 
        104L, 37L, 24L, 19L, 118L, 88L, 42L)), .Names = c("State", "Company", 
        "Employees"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Calculate `min` by group is easy, using `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(Employees ~ State, data, function(x) min(x))
  State Employees
1    AK        24
2    RI        19
```

...or `data.table`:

```
> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(data)
> DT[ , list(Employees = min(Employees)), by = State]
   State Employees
1:    AK        24
2:    RI        19
```

But how do I extract the entire row corresponding to these `min` values, i.e. also including `Company` in the result?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Slightly more elegant:

```
library(data.table)
DT[ , .SD[which.min(Employees)], by = State]

   State Company Employees
1:    AK       D        24
2:    RI       E        19
```

---

Slighly less elegant than using `.SD`, but a bit faster (for data with many groups):

```
DT[DT[ , .I[which.min(Employees)], by = State]$V1]
```

Also, just replace the expression `which.min(Employees)` with `Employees == min(Employees)`, if your data set has multiple identical min values and you'd like to subset all of them.

See also [Subset rows corresponding to max value by group using data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-rows-corresponding-to-max-value-by-group-using-data-table).

Comment: How to get it if the number should return the minimum but based on the number of frequency that number has been used?

Answer (score 89):

Here a `dplyr` solution ( Note that I am not a regular user ):

```
library(dplyr)    
data %>% 
    group_by(State) %>% 
    slice(which.min(Employees))
```

As [jazzurro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304471/jazzurro) notes in the comments, as of `dplyr` version 1.0.0, there is also now a built-in function `slice_min`:

```
data %>% 
   group_by(State) %>% 
   slice_min(order_by = Employees)
```

Comment: With dplyr 1.0.0, you can achieve the same in the following way: `group_by(data, State) %>% slice_min(order_by = Employees)`.

Comment: dplyr 1.1.0 added the experimental argument `by`: `data |> slice_min(Employees, by = State)`

Answer (score 48):

As this is Google's top hit, I thought I would add some additional options which I find useful to know. The idea is basically to arrange once by `Employees` and then just take the uniques per `State`

Either using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(data)[order(Employees)], by = "State")
#    State Company Employees
# 1:    RI       E        19
# 2:    AK       D        24
```

---

Alternatively, we could also first order and then subset `.SD`. Both of those operations were optimized in the resent data.table versions and `order` is seemingly triggers `data.table:::forderv`, while `.SD[1L]` triggers `Gforce`

```
setDT(data)[order(Employees), .SD[1L], by = State, verbose = TRUE] # <- Added verbose
# order optimisation is on, i changed from 'order(...)' to 'forder(DT, ...)'.
# i clause present and columns used in by detected, only these subset: State 
# Finding groups using forderv ... 0 sec
# Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0 sec
# Getting back original order ... 0 sec
# lapply optimization changed j from '.SD[1L]' to 'list(Company[1L], Employees[1L])'
# GForce optimized j to 'list(`g[`(Company, 1L), `g[`(Employees, 1L))'
# Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0 secs
#    State Company Employees
# 1:    RI       E        19
# 2:    AK       D        24
```

---

Or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  arrange(Employees) %>% 
  distinct(State, .keep_all = TRUE)
#   State Company Employees
# 1    RI       E        19
# 2    AK       D        24
```

---

Another interesting idea borrowed from [@Khashaas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31853101/3001626) awesome answer (with a small modification in form of `mult = "first"` in order to handle multiple matches) is to first find minimum per group and then perform a binary join back. The advantage of this is both the utilization of data.tables `gmin` function (which skips the evaluation overhead) and the *binary join* feature

```
tmp <- setDT(data)[, .(Employees = min(Employees)), by = State]
data[tmp, on = .(State, Employees), mult = "first"]
#    State Company Employees
# 1:    AK       D        24
# 2:    RI       E        19
```

---

**Some benchmarks**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(stringi)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
N <- 1e6
data <- data.frame(State = stri_rand_strings(N, 2, '[A-Z]'),
                   Employees = sample(N*10, N, replace = TRUE))
DT <- copy(data)
setDT(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
str(DT)
str(DT2)

microbenchmark("(data.table) .SD[which.min]: " = DT[ , .SD[which.min(Employees)], by = State],
               "(data.table) .I[which.min]: " = DT[DT[ , .I[which.min(Employees)], by = State]$V1],
               "(data.table) order/unique: " = unique(DT[order(Employees)], by = "State"),
               "(data.table) order/.SD[1L]: " = DT[order(Employees), .SD[1L], by = State],
               "(data.table) self join (on):" = {
                 tmp <- DT[, .(Employees = min(Employees)), by = State]
                 DT[tmp, on = .(State, Employees), mult = "first"]},
               "(data.table) self join (setkey):" = {
                 tmp <- DT2[, .(Employees = min(Employees)), by = State] 
                 setkey(tmp, State, Employees)
                 setkey(DT2, State, Employees)
                 DT2[tmp, mult = "first"]},
               "(dplyr) slice(which.min): " = data %>% group_by(State) %>% slice(which.min(Employees)),
               "(dplyr) arrange/distinct: " = data %>% arrange(Employees) %>% distinct(State, .keep_all = TRUE),
               "(dplyr) arrange/group_by/slice: " = data %>% arrange(Employees) %>% group_by(State) %>% slice(1),
               "(plyr) ddply/which.min: " = ddply(data, .(State), function(x) x[which.min(x$Employees),]),
               "(base) by: " = do.call(rbind, by(data, data$State, function(x) x[which.min(x$Employees), ])))


# Unit: milliseconds
#                             expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval      cld
#    (data.table) .SD[which.min]:   119.66086  125.49202  145.57369  129.61172  152.02872  267.5713   100    d    
#     (data.table) .I[which.min]:    12.84948   13.66673   19.51432   13.97584   15.17900  109.5438   100 a       
#      (data.table) order/unique:    52.91915   54.63989   64.39212   59.15254   61.71133  177.1248   100  b      
#     (data.table) order/.SD[1L]:    51.41872   53.22794   58.17123   55.00228   59.00966  145.0341   100  b      
#     (data.table) self join (on):   44.37256   45.67364   50.32378   46.24578   50.69411  137.4724   100  b      
# (data.table) self join (setkey):   14.30543   15.28924   18.63739   15.58667   16.01017  106.0069   100 a       
#       (dplyr) slice(which.min):    82.60453   83.64146   94.06307   84.82078   90.09772  186.0848   100   c     
#       (dplyr) arrange/distinct:   344.81603  360.09167  385.52661  379.55676  395.29463  491.3893   100     e   
# (dplyr) arrange/group_by/slice:   367.95924  383.52719  414.99081  397.93646  425.92478  557.9553   100      f  
#         (plyr) ddply/which.min:   506.55354  530.22569  568.99493  552.65068  601.04582  727.9248   100       g 
#                      (base) by:  1220.38286 1291.70601 1340.56985 1344.86291 1382.38067 1512.5377   100        h
```

Comment: Nicely done.  Just for completeness / curiosity, I provided a correct plyr solution.  Feel free to include in benchmark... I don't expect it will stand up to `data.table` though.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Updated.

Answer (score 9):

The base function `by` is often useful for working with block data in data.frames. For example

```
by(data, data$State, function(x) x[which.min(x$Employees), ] )
```

It does return the data in a list, but you can collapse that with

```
do.call(rbind, by(data, data$State, function(x) x[which.min(x$Employees), ] ))
```

Answer (score 5):

In *base* you can use `ave` to get `min` per group and compare this with `Employees` and get a logical vector to subset the `data.frame`.

```
data[data$Employees == ave(data$Employees, data$State, FUN=min),]
#  State Company Employees
#4    AK       D        24
#5    RI       E        19
```

Or compare it already in the function.

```
data[as.logical(ave(data$Employees, data$State, FUN=function(x) x==min(x))),]
#data[ave(data$Employees, data$State, FUN=function(x) x==min(x))==1,] #Variant
#  State Company Employees
#4    AK       D        24
#5    RI       E        19
```

Answer (score 3):

Corrected `plyr` solution:

```
ddply(df, .(State), function(x) x[which.min(x$Employees),])
#   State Company Employees
# 1    AK       D        24
# 2    RI       E        19
```

[thanks to @joel.wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098978/2573061)

Answer (score 2):

Using `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
library(magrittr)
data %>% 
  fgroup_by(State) %>% 
  fsummarise(Employees = fmin(Employees))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `data.table` solution:

```
DT[, E_min := min(Employees), by = State][Employees == E_min]
```

Pretty straightforward and among the fastest. Below I rerun **David Arenburg**'s benchmarking with this and the other fastest `data.table` solutions.

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
N <- 1e6
data <- data.frame(State = stri_rand_strings(N, 2, '[A-Z]'),
                   Employees = sample(N * 10, N, replace = TRUE))
DT <- copy(data)
setDT(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)

microbenchmark(
    "(data.table) min column: " = DT3[, E_min := min(Employees), by = State][Employees == E_min],
    "(data.table) .I[which.min]: " = DT[DT[, .I[which.min(Employees)], by = State]$V1],
    "(data.table) order/unique: " = unique(DT[order(Employees)], by = "State"),
    "(data.table) self join (setkey):" = {
        tmp <- DT2[, .(Employees = min(Employees)), by = State]
        setkey(tmp, State, Employees)
        setkey(DT2, State, Employees)
        DT2[tmp, mult = "first"]
    }
)

                             expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
        (data.table) min column:  44.30078 52.17932  68.31826 58.65887  76.89786 184.0207   100
     (data.table) .I[which.min]:  20.34116 26.31244  39.36874 34.01958  42.65439 124.9204   100
      (data.table) order/unique:  70.07820 80.20577 109.71235 95.25586 114.87695 514.4456   100
 (data.table) self join (setkey): 13.48105 16.06614  22.58310 17.35083  22.31206 161.9103   100
```

This solution is most useful if you want just a few columns returned among many, e.g. `[Employees == E_min, ..columns_to_keep]`, in which case it can be even faster.