# return rows with max/min value of column, by group, using plyr::ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I found an answer (now [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24073057/2573061)) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group/24073057#24073057), and I'm curious why it doesn't work.

Question is: return the row corresponding to the minimum value, by group.

So for example, given the dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(State = c(rep('AK',4),rep('RI',4)),
                   Company = LETTERS[1:8],
                   Employees = c(82L, 104L, 37L, 24L, 19L, 118L, 88L, 42L))
```

...the correct answer is:

```
    State Company Employees
 1:    AK       D        24
 2:    RI       E        19
```

as can be obtained, for example, by

```
library(data.table); setDT(df)[ , .SD[which.min(Employees)], by = State]
```

**My question is why this `plyr::ddply` command *doesn't* work:**

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(State), summarise, Employees=min(Employees), 
      Company=Company[which.min(Employees)])
# returns:
#   State Employees Company
# 1    AK        24       A
# 2    RI        19       E
```

In other words, why is `which.min(Employees)` returning 1 for each group, instead of `c(4,1)`?  Note that outside of `ddply`, this works:

```
summarise(df, minEmp = min(Employees), whichMin = which.min(Employees))
#   minEmp whichMin
# 1     19        5
```

I don't use `plyr` much, but I'd like to know the right way to do it, if there's a reasonable one.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I saw you replied to my comment but then it disappeared -- just curious about what the right way to do it using `plyr` would be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm getting the correct answer. not sure about your case..

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(State), function(x) x[which.min(x$Employees),])
  State Company Employees
1    AK       D        24
2    RI       E        19
```

Comment: well that was simple enough, I'll accept when permitted

Comment: now it's giving yo the results? @C8H10N4O2  what was the problem then?

Comment: there's no problem with your solution.  it works.  what I tried before (as described in question) didn't work.