# Efficient way of taking the max date within groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I often have data sets where I have multiple event measures over time and I want to take the maximum date for each event within a month.  I do this by creating a year and month variable and then ordering by date in descending order and then `group_by` all variables except date and then using a `slice` to get the max date.  I heard Hadely say in a video that `arrange` is a slow operation.  I was wondering what the efficient way to do this was within the tidyverse.

Please post base, data.table, other answers as well so that other uses may benefit from this question but my desire here is a tidyverse approach.

### How I do this operation currently:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)
dat <- data_frame(
    date = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2001/01/01'), by="day"), 1000, TRUE),
    cash = sample(1010:1030, 1000, TRUE),
    stage = sample(LETTERS[1:7], 1000, TRUE)
) %>% distinct()


dat %>%
    mutate(
        year = format(date, '%Y'),
        month = format(date, '%B')
    ) %>%
    arrange(desc(date)) %>%
    group_by(cash, stage, year, month) %>%
    slice(1)
```

Comment: `group_by(cash, stage, year, month) %>% slice(which.max(date))`?

Comment: Welp, guess not, yours is faster..

Comment: There are some options/benchmarks [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group).

Comment: You can also use `yearmonth = format(date, '%Y-%m')` instead of two variables

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group)

Comment: Assuming this doesn't get closed as a dupe, you probably want to write your example so that it's extensible to more rows (like assign some `n` that can be used to scale it up).

Comment: I imagine that OP's approach with arrange performs better than the `slice(which.max(date))` approach since the ordering is done only once for the whole data and only the simple `slice(1)` is a grouped operation whereas in the other case `slice(which.max(date))` is done by group. Perhaps it's relevant that in previous dplyr versions, `arrange` used to also order by grouping variables, afaik.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP doesn't include a way to scale up the benchmark, so I'm making my own:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)    

n = 3e6
n_days = 20000

set.seed(10)
dat <- data_frame(
    date = sample(
      seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/01/01') + n_days - 1, by="day")
      , n, TRUE),
    cash = sample(1010:1030, n, TRUE),
    stage = sample(LETTERS[1:7], n, TRUE)
) %>% distinct()

DT = data.table(dat)[, date := as.IDate(date)]
```

Testing:

```
# OP's approach
system.time(
  res <- dat %>%
    mutate(
        year = format(date, '%Y'),
        month = format(date, '%B')
    ) %>%
    arrange(desc(date)) %>%
    group_by(cash, stage, year, month) %>%
    slice(1)
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    9.44    0.09    9.54 

# a data.table way
system.time({
  DTres <- DT[, g := date - mday(date) + 1L ][order(-date), .SD[1L], by=.(cash, stage, g)]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.51    0.00    0.52 

# verify
fsetequal(
  data.table(res[, c("cash","stage","date")])[, date := as.IDate(date)][], 
  DTres[, c("cash","stage","date")]
) # TRUE
```

Translating back to dplyr:

```
system.time({
  newres <- dat %>% mutate(g = date - as.POSIXlt(date)$mday + 1) %>% 
    arrange(desc(date)) %>% group_by(cash, stage, g) %>% slice(1L)
})
# Error, who knows why?

system.time({
  newres <- dat %>% mutate(g = date + 1 - date %>% as.POSIXlt %>% `[[`("mday")) %>% 
    arrange(desc(date)) %>% group_by(cash, stage, g) %>% slice(1L)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.47    0.04    1.52

fsetequal(
  data.table(res[c("date","cash","stage")]),   
  data.table(newres[c("date","cash","stage")])
) # TRUE

# or ...
iddat <- dat %>% mutate(date = data.table::as.IDate(date))
mday <- data.table::mday
system.time({
  borrowres <- iddat %>% arrange(desc(date)) %>% 
    distinct(cash, stage, g = date - mday(date) + 1L)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.92    0.02    0.94 

fsetequal(
  data.table(borrowres[names(DTres)]),   
  DTres
) # TRUE
```

The relative timings didn't change much as I tweaked `n` and `n_days`. Thanks to @Arun for this way of rounding. Previously, I had `round(date, "months")`. It seems that the key is using arithmetic instead of `format`. I'm not sure about the remaining difference in the timings; maybe it can be addressed by using dtplyr. The switch to `arrange %>% distinct` didn't do much beyond cleaning up the syntax.

*Side note:* I'm loading dplyr instead of tidyverse because I don't really know what the latter contains. I tried it with tidyverse and got the same timings, though.

Comment: @Arun I guess you mean `mday`? Yeah, it's 5x faster with `system.time(DTres2 <- DT[, g := date - as.integer(mday(date)) + 1L ][order(-date), .SD[1L], by=.(cash, stage, g)])`  Thanks. I'll edit it later. Feel free to edit; I'm not entirely sure my "why it's faster" is right. (I don't know if as.integer is needed there.. will check later.)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other `data.table` options:

```
f.dt <- function(dat) {
    DT <- data.table(dat)[,yearmon := format(date, "%Y %B")]
    DT[order(-date),idx := 1:.N, 
       by = .(cash, stage, yearmon)
    ][idx == 1, !"idx"][]
}

f2.dt <- function(dat) {
    DT <- data.table(dat)[,yearmon := format(date, "%Y %B")]
    DT[DT[, .I[which.max(date)], 
        by = .(cash, stage, yearmon)]$V1,][]
}
```

The second one uses [Señor O's second approach in the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070773/1869097).

Testing these against

```
f.dplyr <- function(dat) {
    dat %>%
        mutate(
            yearmon = format(date, '%Y %B')
        ) %>%
        arrange(desc(date)) %>%
        group_by(cash, stage, yearmon) %>%
        slice(1)    
}
```

with Frank's data,

```
fsetequal(f.dt(dat), data.table(f.dplyr(dat)))
# [1] TRUE

fsetequal(f2.dt(dat), data.table(f.dplyr(dat)))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    f.dplyr(dat),
    f.dt(dat),
    f2.dt(dat),
    times = 10L
)
# Unit: seconds
#          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  f.dplyr(dat) 3.446304 3.562061 3.601803 3.598340 3.625105 3.860911    10
#     f.dt(dat) 1.525025 1.540881 1.727772 1.561149 1.718817 2.422788    10
#    f2.dt(dat) 1.299834 1.315242 1.510534 1.384346 1.667197 2.262938    10
```

---

**Data**

```
n = 3e6
n_days = 20000

set.seed(10)
dat <- dplyr::data_frame(
    date = sample(
      seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), 
          as.Date('1999/01/01') + n_days - 1, 
          by = "day"), n, TRUE),
    cash = sample(1010:1030, n, TRUE),
    stage = sample(LETTERS[1:7], n, TRUE)
) %>% dplyr::distinct()
```