# Count rows in the past year according to a condition using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

According to [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766130/data-frame-how-to-add-a-column-to-count-previous-occurrences-in-the-last-20-wee), I can add a column with a count of occurrences in the past year in the following way:

```
df[, boundary := date - 365]
df[, counts := df[df, .N,  on = .(id, date < date, date > boundary), by = .EACHI]$N]
```

This works fine for me. However, I want to do this by counting only the number of occurrences where another column has a specific value. For example, given a dataset like this

```
id  type  date
ny  0     2021-09-27   
ny  0     2021-09-09
ny  1     2021-08-01
ny  1     2021-07-07
ch  0     2020-04-01
ch  1     2020-03-01 
ch  0     2020-02-01
```

I want to count only the number of rows where `type = 1`. How can I amend the function above to do this? I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
df[, counts := df[df, .N(type = 1),  on = .(id, date < date, date > boundary), by = .EACHI]$N]
```

EDIT:
Expected output for the above dataset would be:

```
id  type  date         counts
ny  0     2021-09-27   2
ny  0     2021-09-09   2
ny  1     2021-08-01   1  
ny  1     2021-07-07   0  
ch  0     2020-04-01   1
ch  1     2020-03-01   0 
ch  0     2020-02-01   0
```

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: `date < date` doesn't make any sense since this is always `FALSE`.

Comment: Hi @MartinGal, I added an edit to the post showing this :)

Comment: Hmm, it does work for me. I did it in the same way as the accepted post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766130/data-frame-how-to-add-a-column-to-count-previous-occurrences-in-the-last-20-wee)

Comment: @fifigoblin Ah, my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @RonakShah No, it doesn't, it throws an error that the lengths do not match when joining.

Comment: @RonakShah `Supplied 1511 items to be assigned to 1079 items of column 'counts'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.`

Comment: Hi @RonakShah I added more rows to the datasets in the post, hopefully this explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may calculate `sum(type == 1)` instead of `.N`.

```
setDT(df)
df[, boundary := date - 365]

df[, counts := df[df, sum(type == 1),  
      on = .(id, date < date, date > boundary), by = .EACHI]$V1]
df[is.na(counts), counts := 0]
df

#   id type       date   boundary counts
#1: ny    0 2021-09-27 2020-09-27      2
#2: ny    0 2021-09-09 2020-09-09      2
#3: ny    1 2021-08-01 2020-08-01      1
#4: ny    1 2021-07-07 2020-07-07      0
#5: ch    0 2020-04-01 2019-04-02      1
#6: ch    1 2020-03-01 2019-03-02      0
#7: ch    0 2020-02-01 2019-02-01      0
```

Comment: Exactly this - thank you :)