# Return a subset based on a logical comparison against input df

Tags: r

Using R, I am trying to return a single row for each ID, filtering through targets in a df_filter, or the next lowest integer based on the filter.

original df:

```
df:
id   year       
1    2019    
1    2018   
1    2005   
1    2004    
2    2018   
2    2017   
3    1998  
3    1997
3    1996
3    1995
```

the filter:

```
df_filter:
id   year       
1    2017  
2    2018
3    2000
```

the result data frame should look like this:

```
dfnew:
id   year
1    2005
2    2017
3    1998
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack! The thread [Extract row corresponding to minimum value of a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group) presents numerous different approaches and some benchmarks on many of them for comparison purposes.

Comment: Your new output is not clear abiout the logic

Comment: apologies! the purpose is, "given a specific year for the id, what was the most recent previous year the id occurred?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df_filter, on = .(id)][year != i.year, 
      .(year = year[which(year  < i.year)[1]]), id]
#   id year
#1:  1 2005
#2:  2 2017
#3:  3 1998
```

Or using `non-equi` join

```
setDT(df)[, year1 := year][df_filter, .(id, year), 
         on = .(id, year1 < year), mult = 'first']
#    id year
#1:  1 2005
#2:  2 2017
#3:  3 1998
```

Or without assigning (`:=`) in the original dataset

```
setDT(df)[, .(year1 = year, year, id)][df_filter, .(id, year),
        on = .(id, year1 < year), mult = 'first']
```

Or as @thelatemail commented

```
setDT(df)[df_filter, on=.(id, year < year), .(yearM = max(x.year)),
          by=.EACHI][, .(id, year = yearM)]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` with `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_left_join(df, df_filter, by = c("id", "year"),
       match_fun = list(`==`, `<`)) %>% 
  group_by(id = id.x) %>%
  summarise(year = year.x[which(year.x < year.y)[1]])
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id year
#  <int> <int>
#1     1  2005
#2     2  2017
#3     3  1998
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    year = c(2019L, 2018L, 2005L, 2004L, 2018L, 2017L, 1998L, 
    1997L, 1996L, 1995L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
df_filter <- structure(list(id = 1:3, year = c(2017L, 2018L, 2000L)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: @akrun, can you explain the advantage of using structure to create your df dataframe instead of just doing something like id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3); year <- c(2019,2018,2005,2004,2018,2017,1998,1997,1996,1995) ; df <- data.frame(id,year)? Asking so I can learn, not questioning your use!

Comment: @RussThomas  That is a little trick by `dput` function.  You created the `df`, and use `dput(df)`, gets the exact structure that you are using.  It is easier for reproducibility.  In SO, many times, users ask questions with images or just  some format of the data.  But, once we create a code and test, it may not work with their original data because the type may be a problem (having `factor` insstead of `numeric` when taking the `sum`)

Comment: What about a rolling join? - `df_filter[df, on=c("id","year"), roll=-Inf, nomatch=0L][, .SD[1], by=id]` - no idea how it compares speed-wise but it took me a while to figure out so thought I'd share.

Comment: I've gone down the rabbit hole here a bit - also `df[df_filter, on=c("id","year<year"), .(closest=max(x.year)), by=.EACHI]`

Comment: @thelatemail  That is nice.  I also tried it but couldn't fix it the `x.` part

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` we can `left_join` `df` and `df_filter` `by` `id`, `group_by` `id`, `arrange` `year` in descending order and select the first row when the difference between two years is less than 0.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df, df_filter, by = "id") %>%
   arrange(desc(year.x)) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   slice(which.max((year.x - year.y[1L]) < 0L)) %>%
   select(year.x)


#     id year.x
#   <int>  <int>
#1     1   2005
#2     2   2017
#3     3   1998
```

Comment: this is very close! i have updated the df_filter for id "1" to be 2017. the corresponding result in dfnew has been updated.
instead of returning the "closest row", i want to return the next highest integer.
i think there is slightly different logic, but also a small requirement of code...