# R element by element compute, by group

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I'm attempting to do a computation by Id group. would like to use dplyr, but not necessary.  In the history column,i have a string of numbers (all same length, 36). I want to apply the rule, get the largest (max) value, element by element, and get out a new single history, for each Id.
For example, for ID = 1157, the new, single string, would be 
432400000000000000000000000000000000, as those are the largest values for each element, for that ID.  I would like to do this for all Ids (thousands of them).

```
     Id                              history
1  1157 101000000000000000000000000000000000
2  1157 000000000000000000000000000000000000
3  1157 432100000000000000000000000000000000
4  1157 321000000000000000000000000000000000
5  1157 000400000000000000000000000000000000
6  1157 432100000000000000000000000000000000
7  1157 211000000000000000000000000000000000
26 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
27 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
45 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
46 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
47 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
48 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
49 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
50 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
51 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
52 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
53 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
54 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
55 1351 000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Isn't this just max per group? `df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.numeric(history)))` ?

Comment: These two seems to answer your question:- [1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group

Comment: i need it element by element, not which row is max. that example is a bit decieving.

Comment: ahh..I see. Can you update the post with a better example so that the difference is clear ? Also it would be helpful if you could provide `dput` of your sample data.

Comment: Do you mean,  `df %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(new_string = max(history))`? This assign the max value of column `history` in the group to each `Id` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split every `history` value on each character and create a list column and `group_by` `Id` and use `pmax` to get element with maximum value at each position.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_col = map(history, ~strsplit(., "")[[1L]])) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(temp = paste0(Reduce(pmax, new_col), collapse = ""))

#  Id    temp                                
# <int> <chr>                               
#1 1157  432400000000000000000000000000000000
#2 1351  000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

`strsplit` creates a list of characters and since we are using `map` it creates another list hence, the output becomes a nested list which we avoid by using `[[1L]]` so output of `strsplit` is a character vector instead of list.

`new_col` however is a list column and using `Reduce` we compare all the `new_col` values in the group (`Id`) and select the elements with `max`  value element by element using `pmax`.

Another thing to note here is we have `new_col` as list of character vectors which means 1 is "1", 2 is "2" and so on. Ideally `new_col` should have been a list of integer vectors for comparison purposes but here I think it would not matter because we are doing element-wise comparison and it would yield the same result as normal integer comparison. To test a few

```
"2" > "1"
#[1] TRUE
"6" < "1"
#[1] FALSE
```

---

Using the same logic in base R, this would be

```
stack(lapply(split(strsplit(df$history, ""), df$Id), function(x) 
              paste0(Reduce(pmax, x), collapse = "")))

#                                values  ind
#1 432400000000000000000000000000000000 1157
#2 000000000000000000000000000000000000 1351
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(1157L, 1157L, 1157L, 1157L, 1157L, 1157L, 
1157L, 1351L, 1351L, 1351L, 1351L, 1351L, 1351L, 1351L, 1351L, 
1351L, 1351L, 1351L, 1351L, 1351L), history = 
c("101000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"432100000000000000000000000000000000", 
"321000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000400000000000000000000000000000000", 
"432100000000000000000000000000000000", 
"211000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
 "000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
"000000000000000000000000000000000000")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "26", "27", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: that was pretty epic.  can you perhaps explain some of the complexity? Specifically, this map(history, ~strsplit(., "")[[1L]]))   and the "reduce".  the code worked very well. thx u!

Comment: @ElChapo Added some explanation. Hope you find it useful.