# Eliminate specific rows in a dataset

Tags: r

I have a data frame which is in .csv format. This data frame includes 34500 rows. In this file, list of a RNAseq analysis result is present. Here the problem is some genes have multiple results and I should pick 1 entry for each gene and this entry should have the most p value. I edited my data and I have just "Gene symbol" and "p value" information.

How can i remove/eliminate rows which includes genes that should be eliminated according to my rule. I will add a screenshot which shows my problem.

Thanks in advance.

[image: RNF144A, TTTY14, TAS2R8, KIAA0355, GCNT2 are examples of problem.]

Comment: Please add your data with `dput`. Use `dput(head(df,n))` not **images**. Also include sample code and what your rule is.

Comment: I could not write any code,so i did not add. My rule is to eliminate rows, which belong to the genes that have multiple entries, the row with the most p value should remain and the other entries should be eliminated.

Comment: OK, add your comment to your post and add data as suggested above or make a dummy data set. Include a sample of the expected output too.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/24070714/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the blanks (`""`) correspond to repeat entries from the previous non-blank "Gene", change the blanks to `NA` (`na_if`), then use `fill` to change the NA to previous non-NA value, grouped by 'Gene', get the row with the `max` value for 'pvalue'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Gene = na_if(Gene, "")) %>%
    fill(Gene) %>%
    group_by(Gene) %>%
    slice(which.max(pvalue))
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution looks what i look for but when i tried to write R could not find fill function. I install dplyr package succesfully but it does not work.

Comment: @MelihO.  You an just assign to a object `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(...` or  to a new one `df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(..`