# Get min value of column based on 1 other column with all value of column in R

Tags: r, group-by, row

Hei,

I am trying to get the minimal value of a column (ex: maximumDepthInMeters) corresponding for each different species available of the column NameSize, and I am interested of the result; the value of the column CarbonBiomass, per locationID and per expedition. (see example of my data below)

I have been trying this code from this post ([Extract row corresponding to minimum value of a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group))

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(depthint_5sp_Diatoms)
min_of_maxdepth <- DT[ , .SD[maximumDepthInMeters == min(maximumDepthInMeters)], by = NameSize]
```

But it doesnt work for what I want.

I have also tried : (not working, get of course same table)

```
min_value <- depthint_5sp_Diatoms %>% 
  group_by(NameSize, CarbonBiomass, locationID, expedition) %>% 
  slice(which.min(maximumDepthInMeters))
```

[Example of my data: (I have more locationID (ex: P2,P3, etc) and more expedition (ex: 2019706))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWERv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `filter` instead of `slice`:

```r
min_value <- depthint_5sp_Diatoms %>% 
  group_by(NameSize, locationID, expedition) %>% 
  filter(maximumDepthInMeters == min(maximumDepthInMeters))
```

It sounds like maybe you don't want to be grouping by `CarbonBiomass` but I can't tell for sure based on your description

Comment: yes it works...thanks you! I don't want group_by CarbonBiomass  but I wanted in the result, stupid me!