# find first value of a day

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find the first value of the day.

I have the following dataframe

```
time_str = c('2018-03-19 17:00:18', '2018-03-19 18:00:18', '2018-03-19 19:00:18', '2018-03-20 00:01:18', '2018-03-20 08:00:18', '2018-03-21 02:00:18', '2018-03-21 09:00:18')
value= c(1,2,1,3,4,5,9)

df=data.frame(time_str, value)
```

The result should be as dataframe that looks like this:

```
             time_str value
1 2018-03-19 17:00:18     1
2 2018-03-20 00:01:18     3
3 2018-03-21 02:00:18     5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract row corresponding to minimum value of a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group)

Answer (score 2):

Change `time_str` to `POSIXct` type and for each date select the row with earliest time.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(time_str = as.POSIXct(time_str, 'UTC'), 
         date = as.Date(time_str)) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  slice(which.min(time_str)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-date)

#  time_str            value
#  <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 2018-03-19 17:00:18     1
#2 2018-03-20 00:01:18     3
#3 2018-03-21 02:00:18     5
```

Answer (score 1):

With R data.table you could do:

```r
require(data.table)

# set to data.table
setDT(df)
# IDate data type
df[ , date := as.IDate(time_str) ]
# select minimum
df[ , .SD[which.min(date)], date ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a `temp`orary variable containing just the day, then `group_by` that variable, and finally use `slice_head` with `n = 1` to subset the dataframe on the first `value`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(temp = sub(" .*", "", time_str)) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  slice_head(., n = 1)
A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   temp [3]
  time_str            value temp      
  <chr>               <dbl> <chr>     
1 2018-03-19 17:00:18     1 2018-03-19
2 2018-03-20 00:01:18     3 2018-03-20
3 2018-03-21 02:00:18     5 2018-03-21
```