# Extract row corresponding to maximum value by group for multiple variables

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a data frame grouped by `ID` with multiple rows per `ID` and several variables `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.

Here is a toy example:

```
dt <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10), a = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), b = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), c = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), d = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), e = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), f = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), g = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), h = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), i = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For each `ID`, I want to extract the row that represents the maximum value for each variable (taking first or last instance of max value is not a concern). There are plenty of examples of how to do this when only considering one variable [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group). However, I am having difficulty applying this across multiple variables.

Here was my attempt to solve the problem (using `data.table` and `lapply`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
variables = colnames(dt[, 2:10])
dt_max = dt[, lapply(.SD, which.max), .SDcols = variables, by = "ID"]
```

Looking at what this produces, it appears that values are being summed rather than the maximum value being extracted for each `ID`:

```
    ID a b c d e f g h i
 1:  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
 2:  2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 3:  3 1 1 1 1 5 1 1 2 1
 4:  4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 5:  5 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1
 6:  6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 7:  7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 8:  8 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2
 9:  9 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
10: 10 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This is my desired/expected output:

```
    ID a b c d e f g h i
 1:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 2:  2 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
 3:  3 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
 4:  4 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
 5:  5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 6:  6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
 7:  7 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
 8:  8 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
 9:  9 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
10: 10 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I am at a loss for why this would be happening. My only other thought would be to do this the long way for each variable separately, then merging the results together. But this seems like a very inefficient way to solve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm curious about "extract the row that represents the maximum value for each variable". Based on the link you provided, does your result need to be list of then matrix?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you need `dt[, lapply(.SD, max), .SDcols = variables, by = "ID"]` ?

Comment: For a tidyverse solution, look at `slice_max()`.  As you will potentially have a different row selected for the max of each variable, you need to specify the format of your desired output.  There are many possibilities...

Comment: Simpler: `dt1[, lapply(.SD, which.max), by = "ID"]`. The argument `.SDcols` is not needed. And I'm not seeing anything wrong with the output.

Comment: @RonakShah and Limey: I have edited the question with my desired output. Also, Ronak's solution works. Why would `max` work, but not `which.max`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` and `which.max` are two different functions doing different things. `max` would give the max value in a vector whereas `which.max` would give position of the max value in the vector.

```
x <- 4:1

max(x)
#[1] 4
which.max(x)
#[1] 1
```

Here `which.max` returns 1 because 4 is present at the 1st position in the vector `x`.

So if you need `max` values in multiple columns, you should use `max` and not `which.max`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
variables = colnames(dt[, 2:10])

dt[, lapply(.SD, max), .SDcols = variables, ID]

#    ID a b c d e f g h i
# 1:  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# 2:  2 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
# 3:  3 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
# 4:  4 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
# 5:  5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
# 6:  6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
# 7:  7 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
# 8:  8 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
# 9:  9 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
#10: 10 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```