# How to summarize by group while retrieving values from columns that weren't summarized

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm trying to summarize a data frame, while grouping by a variable. My problem is that when doing such summarizing procedure, I lose other columns that I need.

Consider the following data:

```r
df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~id, ~year, ~my_value,
    1,   2010,  2,
    1,   2013,  2,
    1,   2014,  2,
    2,   2010,  4,
    2,   2012,  3,
    2,   2014,  4,
    2,   2015,  2,
    3,   2015,  3,
    3,   2010,  3,
    3,   2011,  3
  )
```

I want to group by `id` in order to collapse `my_value` to a single value. I use the following algorithm:

1. IF all values of `my_value` are identical, then simply return the first value, i.e, `my_value[1]`.
2. ELSE return the smallest value, i.e., `min(my_value)`.

So I wrote a small function that does it:

```r
my_func <- function(x) {
  if (var(x) == 0) {
    return(x[1])
  }
  # else:
  min(x)
}
```

And now I can use either `dplyr` or `data.table` to summarize by `id`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# dplyr
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(my_min_val = my_func(my_value))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      id my_min_val
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1          2
#> 2     2          2
#> 3     3          3

# data.table
setDT(df)[, .(my_min_val = my_func(my_value)), by = "id"]
#>    id my_min_val
#> 1:  1          2
#> 2:  2          2
#> 3:  3          3
```

So far so good. **My problem** is that I lost the `year` value. I want the respective `year` value for each chosen `my_value`.

My desired output should look like:

```r
# desired output
desired_output <- 
  tribble(~id, ~my_min_val, ~year,
          1,   2,           2010,  # because for id 1, var(my_value) is 0, and hence my_value[1] corresponds to year 2010
          2,   2,           2015,  # because for id 2, var(my_value) is not 0, and hence min(my_value) (which is 2) corresponds to year 2015
          3,   3,           2015)  # because for id 3, var(my_value) is 0, hence my_value[1] corresponds to year 2015
```

I especially seek a `data.table` solution because my real data is very large (over 1 million rows) and with many groups. Thus efficiency is important. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Extract row corresponding to minimum value of a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use the condition in `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
my_func <- function(x) if(var(x) == 0) 1 else which.min(x)
df %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   slice(my_func(my_value)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id  year my_value
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1  2010        2
2     2  2015        2
3     3  2015        3
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[my_func(my_value)], id]$V1]
   id year my_value
1:  1 2010        2
2:  2 2015        2
3:  3 2015        3
```

---

Or with `slice_min` and `with_ties = FALSE`

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    slice_min(n = 1, order_by = my_value, with_ties = FALSE)  %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id  year my_value
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1  2010        2
2     2  2015        2
3     3  2015        3
```

Comment: Thanks. It is important to me to get the *first* element when `var(my_value) == 0`  (rather than just the `min()`) *because* I need the respective year of the first element in the scenario where all elements are identical.

Comment: @Emman what about the update

Comment: Yes! The first seems perfect. I'm not sure about the second option. Does the 2nd way follow the same condition?

Comment: @Emman I guess the `var` is 0 is when all elements are the same right?  there may be some difference

Comment: yes I guess so. Do you happen to know a `data.table` equivalent (to the first method)?

Comment: @Emman  Yes,   instead of `var(my_value) == 0` you may also use `n_distinct(my_value) == 1` because `var` have some limitations i.e. numeric only type

Comment: @Emman updated the post with `data.table`

Comment: Wow you're incredible. Thank you very much.

Comment: As for `var()` being limited, yes I know. I think I'll go with `data.table::uniqueN(x) == 1`