# How to get the maximum value from one column grouped by other columns in R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my dataframe

```
DF <- data.frame(plot=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), 
        id=c("A","B","A","B","B","C","B","C"),
        share=c(0.2,0.6,0.2,0.45,0.55,0.3,0.4,0.3))
```

What I need is to get per `plot` the `id` with the maximum share, so the final data frame would look like this:

```
max <- data.frame(plot=c(1,2,3),
         id=c("B","B","C"))
```

I know that there is a way with `data.table` and it will usually work, but I want to avoid it, because I need this inside of a function, and for some reason the function does not run with the `data.table` package loaded, because there are several functions of `base` R that overlap, so if possible I would like another approach.

Comment: plot 3 has a max share of 0.4, giving B not C as you have above

Comment: @pluke, no because the two shares of C should be added together

Comment: ah, ok, I'll amend

Comment: why is plot 1 giving B, the sum of A is also 0.6:  `DF %>% 
  group_by(plot, id) %>% 
  summarise(plot_sum = sum(share))`

Comment: my bad, that was a typo, I'll edit

Comment: Have also a look at [Select the row with the maximum value in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328), [Extract row corresponding to minimum value of a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714) and [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `tidyverse` you could do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  group_by(plot, id) %>% 
  summarise(plot_sum = sum(share)) %>%
  filter(plot_sum == max(plot_sum)) %>%
  select(-plot_sum)
```

Comment: As mentioned above, this approach does not summarizes the ```share``` for same ```id```'s per ```plot```.

Comment: have fixed, see above

Answer (score 0):

In *base* you can first use `aggregate` and then `ave` to get `max` per group.

```
aggregate(share ~ ., DF, sum) |>
  (\(.) .[ave(.$share, .$plot, FUN=max) == .$share, c("plot", "id")])()
#  plot id
#1    1  B
#3    2  B
#5    3  C
```