# Extract rows for first occurrence of a variable prior to the occurrence of an event

Tags: r, filter, grouping

Trying to extract the first occurrence of a variable in a data frame PRIOR to a specific value already selected in a data frame. Specifically, the output of `head(df)` is:

```
date discharge     event event.isolation some.column
1/1/2016  7.782711         NA  NA             FALSE
1/2/2016  7.349389  -5.567748  none            TRUE
1/3/2016  7.053813  -4.021769  none            TRUE
1/4/2016  7.421568   5.213554  none            TRUE
1/5/2016  5.722443 -22.894418  none            TRUE
1/6/2016  5.497342  -3.933662  none            TRUE
1/7/2016  5.347890  -6.898281  none            TRUE
1/8/2016  7.983489   4.289382  none            TRUE
1/9/2016  8.488293  -19.28304  none            TRUE
```

I'd like to find the `date` of the first `discharge` value of 7.7 or greater before each `event` of -22 or less. In other words, I know each `event` of interest; I would like to iteratively search backwards to find the first `discharge` value of 7.7 or greater prior to each selected `event`.

I'm basically trying to combine [Extract rows for the first occurrence of a variable in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944334/extract-rows-for-the-first-occurrence-of-a-variable-in-a-data-frame) with [Select row prior to first occurrence of an event by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441367/select-row-prior-to-first-occurrence-of-an-event-by-group), but am having difficulty  so.

The desired result would be `df[1, ]` as it contains the first `discharge` value (working backwards) that exceeds 7.7, prior to the `event` in row 5 that I've selected.

Comment: if you show your expected output answers will come easier and in better quality

Comment: 1. post result of `dput(head(df))` 2. show your **desired result** like the example data

Comment: Your `df` seems to be missing the header of one of the columns. Also, could you provide a few extra lines?

Comment: @MKBakker I added a couple more; does that help?

Comment: @BrynnO'donnell a few extra lines where event < -22 would help, because solutions will usually work better if they come for as representative examples as possible

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution, but it works for the example.

This first defines intervals to looks (one interval for each `event < -22`). Then looks for the first occurrence of `discharge > 7.7`

I am assuming in this example that you do not want to find rows where `event < -22` AND `discharge > 7.7`, even if that would be the first occurence of `discharge > 7.7` since the last event

```
df <- read.csv(text = 'date discharge     event event.isolation some.column
1 1/1/2016  7.782711         NA  <NA>           FALSE
 2 1/2/2016  7.349389  -5.567748  none            TRUE
 3 1/3/2016  7.053813  -4.021769  none            TRUE
 4 1/4/2016  7.421568   5.213554  none            TRUE
 5 1/5/2016  5.722443 -22.894418  none            TRUE
 6 1/6/2016  5.497342  -3.933662  none            TRUE
 7 1/7/2016  5.347890  -6.898281  none            TRUE
 8 1/8/2016  7.983489   4.289382  none            TRUE',sep="")

## look which rows have a value for event < 22 and also include row 0 to define the first interval to look
 d <- c(0,which(df$event < -22))

## Each interval is defined as d[i] to d[i+1], where intervals are skipped where these are equal (because then you would return rows where both event < -22 and discharge > 7.7
new.df <- NULL
 for(i in 1:(length(d)-1)) {
  if(d[i+1] > (d[i] + 1)) {
   ## this will look only in the interval and return the first row for which the condition discharge>7.7 is TRUE
   new.df <- subset(df[(d[i]+1):(d[i+1]-1),], discharge>7.7)[1,]
  }
}
```