# Modification of "data.table" to give first 10% of each group

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

So I have a code here:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.min(Julian_Day)]., (species,Year)]
```

Example of the df:

```
df=data.frame(
  year=c(1901,1901,1901,1901,1901,1901,1901,1901,1901,1901,1901,1901,1901),
  temp=c(29,25,21,26,20,20,26,25,24,23,23,24,26),
  habitat=c("fst","fld","city","city","fst","fld","fst","road","river","river","city","city","city"),
  species=c("blu","blu","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink"),
  day= c(34,87,93,79,56,98,100,187,54,14,63,57,23))
```

what I want the new subset to look like:

```
dfout <- data.frame(
       year=c(1901,1901,1901),
       temp=c(29,25,21),
       habitat=c("fst","fld","river"),
       species=c("blu","blu","pink"),
       day=c(34,87,14),
       first10= c(NA,NA,23)
)
```

So this new subset would give me a new row with the mean temp for the first 10%(based on day) of the observations for EACH species for EACH year ( I have from years 1901-2000 and 100 species). As can be seen from above, the blu species only had 2 observations for 1901, therefore there is not enough data to give a mean for the first10% so NA is returned. Secondly, the observations that were not used to calculated the first 10% of observations were omitted from the new subset. If there were say, 30 observations of the pink species in 1901, then 3 rows would have been returned in the new subset, all with the same values in the first10% column.

Comment: I don't know why this has attracted downvotes. If y'all think it has been asked before, please point out the duplicate.

Comment: @Frank my guess it was doewnvoted because the example isn't reproducible?

Comment: Thanks for posting an example, but could you modify it so it is easy to copy-paste into the R console?

Comment: sure, i'm just not sure what i need to change. sorry, i'm really new to this all.

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed it properly!

Comment: Fyi, you can check if you fixed it by copy-pasting it into the R console yourself. Your code still did not work, but I've fixed it so now it does (adding commas and quotes where needed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The special variable `.N` stores the number of observations in the subset for each `(species,Year)` group, so you can select `.SD[(1:.N)/.N < .05]`.

Alternately, it is more efficient to avoid `.SD`, which can be done here using

```
setDT(df)
df[df[,.I[(1:.N)/.N < .05],.(species,Year)]$V1]
```

`.I` is another special variable, holding row numbers in `df`. I borrowed this way of using `.I` from @eddi's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table/16574176#16574176). Both `.N` and `.I` can be read about in the documentation by typing `?data.table`.

---

*Update.* In light of your more complicated request, I'm appending to my original answer:

```
df[,{
    r10s     <- 1:.N/.N < .1
    myrows   <- if(sum(r10s)>0){r10s}else{TRUE}
    c(
        .SD[myrows],
        list(first10=mean(day[r10s]))
    )
},.(species,year)]
```

This returns `NaN` for `first10` when the mean cannot be computed, as is standard in R:

```
   species year temp habitat day first10
1:     blu 1901   29     fst  34     NaN
2:     blu 1901   25     fld  87     NaN
3:    pink 1901   21    city  93      93
```

Comment: Fairly sure, yes; I mean, it makes sense to me that working with `.I` split up by the grouping variables should be faster than `.SD` in the first call, especially if there are many columns. And in the second call, subsetting by row numbers should be pretty cheap. `$` costs nothing, right? It just grabs an element from a list by string matching names in that list.

Comment: I just tried this code in R and it looks like it could work but when I try making it a new dataframe, and then I type in that dataframe name it returns back "NULL" and it doesn't give a new column with the mean for each species for each year...

Comment: @John Okay. If you can make what you see into a reproducible example, I bet we can find a solution.

Comment: okay, so I fixed up my question but this time i made it for the first 10% of observations instead of 5%. please feel free to ask any questions!

Comment: @John I've updated my answer to match your output. If this isn't exactly what you're looking for, I hope it will be a useful guide at least. If you have another substantially different question after this, it'd be best to post it as a separate question, I think.