# Subsetting columns data.table using group by

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to extract extra columns form a data.table while grouping it and selecting the minimum value?

```
DT <- data.table(events)
firstOrders <- as.data.frame(DT[,min(property_time),by=property_.uid])
```

In this example,  the orderids (this is a column in the events-df) should be extracted, so the ordernumber where time is minimum in the userid-group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess we want to get rows that have the `min` value of 'property_time', grouped by 'property_.uid'.  In that case, we can use `which.min` to get the numeric index and use that to subset the dataset (`.SD`).

```
 DT[,.SD[which.min(property_time)],by=property_.uid]
```

A faster option would be to get the row index with `.I` and then subset the dataset

```
 i1 <- DT[,.I[which.min(property_time)],by=property_.uid]$V1
 DT1 <- DT[i1]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
DT <- data.table(property_.uid=rep(1:3, each=3), 
   property_time=sample(1:15, 9, replace=TRUE), OtherCol=rnorm(9))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the second method is indeed ways faster!

Comment: I have to wait for 6 minutes

Comment: @BobbiusMatthiAdriaans  No problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Source for the latter option (eddi's answer -- maybe this is a dupe?): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/1191259 Worth keeping in mind that the `.SD` approach is in the process of being optimized (as tracked by checkmarks here): https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735

Comment: @Frank It sure looks like a dupe.  Feel free to close it as a dupe.  Thanks for the github link.