# Speed up data.table subsetting by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have nearly 10m rows and I want to choose only first three rows from each group.

I use

```
data[x == 1 | y > -6, .SD[1:3], by = z]
```

I need to get as a result

[image]

but it is very slow, because 10M it is only train set. So maybe any ideas how to optimize this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: What version of `data.table` are you running? Have you read the [binary search](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) vignette?

Comment: @MichaelChirico data.table 1.9.6

Comment: [Update to the development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) -- there's recently been some `GForce` optimization of the operation you're doing.

Comment: Are you aware of this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/1191259 Also, I guess you want `seq_len(min(.N,3))` in case a z-group doesn't have three rows.

Comment: @Frank first I order data.table by z asc and y decs. I have not mentioned it in my question. Sorry. How could I add other columns to the output?

Comment: @VitaliyRadchenko I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You could edit your question text to clarify.

Comment: Try `data[data[x == 1L | y > -6L, .I[1:3], by=z]$V1]` until this case is optimised.

Comment: @Frank I've added an image.

Comment: @Arun Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not reproducible. I recommend to read how to ask SO questions on R tag to make the R tag on SO a solid knowledge base rather than fast and much more temporal Q&A.

Sorry for off-topic.

You can potentially get a significant speed-up when using data.table index. It currently requires to filter only on single variable. In your case you would look like:

```
set2key(data, x)
ix = data[x == 1, which = TRUE]
iy = data[y > -6, which = TRUE] # this will not use index (yet)!
data[union(ix, iy), ...]
```

Use `options("datatable.verbose"=TRUE)` to ensure you are using indexes.

The code is not reproducible due to lack of sample of data. So I cannot provide any benchmark, which may be valuable because potential speed-up depends on the data, and may results in slow down instead.

Comment: The best answer is `data[data[x == 1L | y > -6L, .I[1:3], by=z]$V1]`. Thank you.

Comment: @VitaliyRadchenko It depends on your data. The package does special optimization when you use a single inequality test at a time (as Jan does in this answer), so it may be faster in some cases.

Comment: @VitaliyRadchenko Generally it depends on cardinality of data.