# Subset all rows before negative value in group

Tags: r, data.table

I have data.table

```
X = data.table(x = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), y = c(3,2,1,-1,5,7,4,-2,3,5))
```

I want to subset only rows which are above negative values in one group:

```
res = data.table(x = c(1,1,1,2,2), y = c(3,2,1,7,4)
```

From five values in first group, I want to get only first three, because fourth is negative, and the same with second group.

Comment: You mean: X[y>=0] ? Your example seems to have mistake in it

Comment: @user3293236 I want to subset rows before negative value. I can have non-negative values after it, but I don't want to subset them. Look at my result and compare with your code. The result is not the same.

Comment: `X[, .SD[1:(which.max(y<0)-1L)], by = x]`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus Exactly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Standard reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16573995/1191259

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two options:

```
X[, .SD[seq_len(which.max(y<0)-1L)], by = x]
```

Or (perhaps more efficient because it avoids `.SD`):

```
X[ X[, .I[seq_len(which.max(y<0)-1L)], by = x]$V1 ]
```

Comment: +1.  Really have to get to issue [#613](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/613): Optimize `.SD[i]` query to keep the elegance but make it faster unchanged

Answer (score 1):

We may also do

```
X[, .SD[cummin(sign(y))>0], x]
#   x y
#1: 1 3
#2: 1 2
#3: 1 1
#4: 2 7
#5: 2 4
```