# R data.table "by" for "i"

Tags: r, data.table

In a given data.table what would be the syntax to select column V1 where V2 = max(V2), grouped by V3.

For example:
In the mtcars dataset, I would like to find out what is the **hp** that corresponds to the observation equal to **max(disp)**, grouped by **cyl**

Here is my ungraceful solution, using *which*:

```
mtcars <- data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[which(mtcars$disp %in% mtcars[, max(disp), by = .(cyl)]$V1), .(cyl,hp)]
   cyl  hp
1:   6 110
2:   4  62
3:   8 205
```

Is there a more "data.table" way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `.I`:

```
mtcars[mtcars[, .I[which.max(disp)], by = cyl]$V1, .(cyl, hp)]
#   cyl  hp
#1:   6 110
#2:   4  62
#3:   8 205
```

Or

```
mtcars[, hp[disp == max(disp)], by=cyl]
#   cyl  V1
#1:   6 110
#2:   4  62
#3:   8 205
```

And your own approach could be slightly shortened to:

```
mtcars[disp %in% mtcars[, max(disp), by = .(cyl)]$V1, .(cyl,hp)]
```

Answer (score 7):

We can try the join

```
mtcars[mtcars[, list(disp=max(disp)), by = cyl], 
    on = c('cyl', 'disp')][, c('cyl', 'hp'), with=FALSE]
#   cyl  hp
#1:   6 110
#2:   4  62
#3:   8 205
```

---

Or here is a shorter version to get the expected output.

```
mtcars[, .SD[disp==max(disp), .(hp)], by = cyl]
#   cyl  hp
#1:   6 110
#2:   4  62
#3:   8 205
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mtcars[,ismax:=disp==max(disp),by=cyl][ismax==T, .(cyl, hp)]
   cyl  hp
1:   6 110
2:   4  62
3:   8 205
```

I keep arriving at near-identical solutions to others. Ah well...

```
mtcars[,.SD[disp == max(disp)], by = cyl, .SDcols = c("disp", "hp")][,.(cyl, hp)]
```

Comment: This method unnecessarily create  new column in the original data

Comment: Good point, it just seemed like a short and easy solution though. Let me think how to make the same output without creating new column.