# Filter between a Start point and Stop point

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
ID  Cond    Time1   Time2
1   2       Start   Stop1
1   3       Start   abc
1   1       abc     Stop2
1   2       Start   abc
1   2       abc     Stop1
2   2       Start   abc
2   4       abc     jkl
2   3       abc     jkl
2   2       abc     jkl
2   3       abc     Stop2
3   2       Start   abc
3   3       abc     Stop2
3   2       Start   Stop1
3   3       Start   Stop1
3   3       Start   abc
3   2       abc     jkl
3   4       baba    Stop1
4   2       Start   Stop2
4   1       Start   asd
4   2       abc     Stop2
```

And I need to filter the data based on a couple of criteria. If `Cond = 2` and `Time1 = Start`, and I need to filter until the first stopping point (either `Stop1` or `Stop2`). Essentially, it should look like this:

```
ID  Cond    Time1   Time2
1   2       Start   Stop1
1   2       Start   abc
1   2       abc     Stop1
2   2       Start   abc
2   4       abc     jkl
2   3       abc     jkl
2   2       abc     jkl
2   3       abc     Stop2
3   2       Start   abc
3   3       abc     Stop2
3   2       Start   Stop1
4   2       Start   Stop2
```

Also, the real dataset has over 140,000 observations, so efficienicy is key. I was thinking about using the `dplyr` package, but not sure how to go about this problem.

Comment: To help people answer your question, please post a MWE.

Comment: @Nick What is a MWE?

Comment: Can you explain why the third row is `1 2 abc Stop1` instead `1 1 abc Stop2`?

Comment: Minimal Working Example: (see here)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Comment: @mbiron `Stop1` and `Stop2` are only indications of different kinds of stops, not sequential in any way. You could think of them as `StopA` and `StopB`.

Comment: @Nick, The link does not work

Comment: @MikeyMike I have to filter on `Cond = 2 & Time1 = Start`, until we reach a stop. Otherwise `cond = 3` does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
dframe = read.table(header = T, text = "ID  Cond    Time1   Time2
1   2       Start   Stop1
                    1   3       Start   abc
                    1   1       abc     Stop2
                    1   2       Start   abc
                    1   2       abc     Stop1
                    2   2       Start   abc
                    2   4       abc     jkl
                    2   3       abc     jkl
                    2   2       abc     jkl
                    2   3       abc     Stop2
                    3   2       Start   abc
                    3   3       abc     Stop2
                    3   2       Start   Stop1
                    3   3       Start   Stop1
                    3   3       Start   abc
                    3   2       abc     jkl
                    3   4       baba    Stop1
                    4   2       Start   Stop2
                    4   1       Start   asd
                    4   2       abc     Stop2")

library(dplyr)

# add index
dframe = data.frame(index = 1:nrow(dframe), dframe)
head(dframe)

# get starting points
start_points = dframe %>%
  filter(Cond == 2 & Time1 == 'Start') %>%
  select(index, ID)

# get stopping points
stop_points = dframe %>%
  filter(substr(Time2, 1, 4) == 'Stop') %>%
  select(index, ID)

# get the stopping point associated with each start point
start_stop = start_points %>%
  left_join(stop_points, by = "ID") %>%
  filter(index.x <= index.y) %>%
  group_by(ID, index.x) %>%
  summarise(index.y = min(index.y)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rename(start_index = index.x, stop_index = index.y)

# add rows between
result = start_stop %>%
  left_join(dframe, by = "ID") %>%
  filter(start_index <= index, index <= stop_index) %>%
  select(-c(start_index, stop_index, index))

> result
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]

ID  Cond  Time1  Time2
(int) (int) (fctr) (fctr)
1      1     2  Start  Stop1
2      1     2  Start    abc
3      1     2    abc  Stop1
4      2     2  Start    abc
5      2     4    abc    jkl
6      2     3    abc    jkl
7      2     2    abc    jkl
8      2     3    abc  Stop2
9      3     2  Start    abc
10     3     3    abc  Stop2
11     3     2  Start  Stop1
12     4     2  Start  Stop2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[,     s0 := cumsum(Cond==2 & Time1 == "Start")]
DF[.N:1, s1 := cumsum(Time2 %like% "Stop")]

DF[, .SD[ s1 == s1[1L] ], by=s0]

    s0 ID Cond Time1 Time2 s1
 1:  1  1    2 Start Stop1 10
 2:  2  1    2 Start   abc  8
 3:  2  1    2   abc Stop1  8
 4:  3  2    2 Start   abc  7
 5:  3  2    4   abc   jkl  7
 6:  3  2    3   abc   jkl  7
 7:  3  2    2   abc   jkl  7
 8:  3  2    3   abc Stop2  7
 9:  4  3    2 Start   abc  6
10:  4  3    3   abc Stop2  6
11:  5  3    2 Start Stop1  5
12:  6  4    2 Start Stop2  2
```

`.SD` is the Subset of Data associated with each `by=s0` group. The `.N:1` in the second line reverses the data temporarily to create `s1`. If you don't want to keep the new columns around, they can be removed like `DF[, s0 := NULL][, s1 := NULL]` or `DF[, c("s0", "s1") := NULL]`.

If the last line is slow, it is worth trying [@eddi's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/1191259):

```
DF[DF[, .I[ s1 == s1[1L] ], by=s0]$V1]
```

Comment: Good use of `cumsum`

Comment: @Frank I realized this includes all other conditions as well when I apply it to my dataset

Comment: @akash87 I am not sure what you mean without additional context. If you mean that start and stop must always both appear in a run of Cond==2... I guess your example and initial description did not cover it, yeah.

Comment: @Frank I meant that it must start with a `Cond == 2` and end at the `Stop1` or `Stop2`. I think I misread your code, but it works now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map` to conditionally construct the series of rows you want to select, where an anonymous function can be used to judge if the start time has condition 2. Here is a solution, where we used the `data.table` for syntax sugar:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[unlist(Map(function(t1, t2) if(t1 %in% which(Cond == 2)) t1:t2 else NULL, 
              which(Time1 == "Start"), which(grepl("Stop", Time2))))]
    ID Cond Time1 Time2
 1:  1    2 Start Stop1
 2:  1    2 Start   abc
 3:  1    2   abc Stop1
 4:  2    2 Start   abc
 5:  2    4   abc   jkl
 6:  2    3   abc   jkl
 7:  2    2   abc   jkl
 8:  2    3   abc Stop2
 9:  3    2 Start   abc
10:  3    3   abc Stop2
11:  3    2 Start Stop1
12:  4    2 Start Stop2
```

To boost the performance a little bit:

```
df[{ cond2 = which(Cond == 2); 
     unlist(Map(function(t1, t2) if(t1 %in% cond2) t1:t2 else NULL, 
                which(Time1 == "Start"), which(grepl("Stop", Time2)))) }]
```

Comment: in your code, why do you have `t1:t2`? I am not as familiar with the `data.table` package.

Comment: `t1:t2` will construct a vector of rows from where `Time1 == "Start"` to where `Time2 == "Stop1/2"` but conditionally which happens only when the `Start` has condition `2` which I think is what you mean. `data.table` here is mainly to save some typing, probably will have some performance boost. This should also work in base `R`.

Comment: Interesting! Now I have read that `Map` is a wrapper to mapply, Do you use `map` because of how `data.table` reads a data frame?

Comment: No I use `Map` because it has only three letters. :)