# Selecting non `NA` values from duplicate rows with `data.table` -- when having more than one grouping variable

Tags: r, data.table, distinct-values

I want to keep distinct rows on a data frame, with an algorithm that chooses the *last* value per group (as `dplyr::distinct()` does by default), but only if it's not `NA`. I've seen [this great answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40315567/6105259) that relies on `data.table`, but I can't scale it to data with more than one grouping variable.

To demonstrate the problem, I start with the minimal example that does work, then scale it up. So first, consider the following data:

```r
library(tibble)

df_id_and_type <-
  tibble::tribble(
        ~id, ~type,
          1,   "A",
          1,    NA,
          2,   "B",
          3,   "A",
          3,    NA,
          3,   "D",
          3,    NA,
          4,    NA,
          4,   "C",
          5,   "A",
          6,    NA,
          6,   "B",
          6,    NA
        )
```

I want to get the distinct `type` values per `id`, by choosing the last value unless it's `NA`. If the last *is* `NA` then go up until there's non-`NA`. So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40315567/6105259) shows us how to do it with `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

dt_id_and_type        <- as.data.table(df_id_and_type)
dt_id_and_type$typena <- is.na(dt_id_and_type$type)
setorderv(dt_id_and_type, c("typena","id"), order = c(-1, 1))
dt_id_and_type[!duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE), c("id", "type"), with = FALSE]
#>    id type
#> 1:  1    A
#> 2:  2    B
#> 3:  3    D
#> 4:  4    C
#> 5:  5    A
#> 6:  6    B
```

---

But what to do if we have more than one grouping variable (i.e, not only `id`)? In the following example I add a `year` variable:

```r
df_id_year_and_type <-
  df_id_and_type %>%
  add_column(year = c(2002, 2002, 2008, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2013, 2020, 2020, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2012), 
             .before = "type")

df_id_year_and_type
#> # A tibble: 13 x 3
#>       id  year type 
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     1  2002 A    
#>  2     1  2002 <NA> 
#>  3     2  2008 B    
#>  4     3  2010 A    
#>  5     3  2010 <NA> 
#>  6     3  2010 D    
#>  7     3  2013 <NA> 
#>  8     4  2020 <NA> 
#>  9     4  2020 C    
#> 10     5  2009 A    
#> 11     6  2010 <NA> 
#> 12     6  2010 B    
#> 13     6  2012 <NA>
```

My expected output would be:

```r
## # A tibble: 8 x 3
##      id  year type 
##   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
## 1     1  2002 A    
## 2     2  2008 B    
## 3     3  2010 D    
## 4     3  2013 NA   # for id 3 in year 2013 there was only `NA`, so that's what we get
## 5     4  2020 C    
## 6     5  2009 A    
## 7     6  2010 B    
## 8     6  2012 NA   # same as comment above
```

---

Any idea how I could scale the solution that worked in 1-grouping-var case to the current data? The first 2 lines of code are no-brainer:

```r
dt_id_year_and_type        <- as.data.table(df_id_year_and_type)
dt_id_year_and_type$typena <- is.na(dt_id_year_and_type$type)
setorderv(dt_id_year_and_type, c("typena","id"), order = c(-1, 1)) # <--- how to account for `year`?
dt_id_year_and_type[!duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE), c("id", "type"), with = FALSE] # <--- here too...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some data.table-based solutions.

```
setDT(df_id_year_and_type)
```

#### method 1

`na.omit(df_id_year_and_type, cols="type")` drops `NA` rows based on column `type`.
`unique(df_id_year_and_type[, .(id, year)], fromLast=TRUE)` finds all the groups.
And by joining them (using the last match: `mult="last"`), we obtain the desired output.

```
na.omit(df_id_year_and_type, cols="type"
        )[unique(df_id_year_and_type[, .(id, year)], fromLast=TRUE), 
          on=c('id', 'year'), 
          mult="last"]

#       id  year   type
#    <num> <num> <char>
# 1:     1  2002      A
# 2:     2  2008      B
# 3:     3  2010      D
# 4:     3  2013   <NA>
# 5:     4  2020      C
# 6:     5  2009      A
# 7:     6  2010      B
# 8:     6  2012   <NA>
```

#### method 2

```
df_id_year_and_type[df_id_year_and_type[, .I[which.max(cumsum(!is.na(type)))], .(id, year)]$V1,]
```

#### method 3

(likely slower because of `[` overhead)

```
df_id_year_and_type[, .SD[which.max(cumsum(!is.na(type)))], .(id, year)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose this solution in which you exclude the unwanted rows prior to `unique`. If all observations for a group are `NA`, `sum(is.na(x)) / .N` is equal to 1 and we proceed from there

```
library(tibble)
library(data.table)

df_id_and_type <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~id, ~type,
    1,   "A",
    1,    NA,
    2,   "B",
    3,   "A",
    3,    NA,
    3,   "D",
    3,    NA,
    4,    NA,
    4,   "C",
    5,   "A",
    6,    NA,
    6,   "B",
    6,    NA
  )


df_id_year_and_type <-
  df_id_and_type %>%
  add_column(year = c(2002, 2002, 2008, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2013, 2020, 2020, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2012), 
             .before = "type")

# convert to data.table
dt_id_year_and_type <- as.data.table(df_id_year_and_type)

# define grouping vars
grouping_vars <- c("id", "year")

# are all types na for a group?
dt_id_year_and_type[, na_ratio := sum(is.na(type)) / .N, 
                    by = c(grouping_vars)]

# remove all lines that are NA, except they are from a group in which all 
# observations are NA
dt_id_year_and_type <- dt_id_year_and_type[na_ratio == 1 | !is.na(type)]

# sort correctly
setorderv(dt_id_year_and_type, grouping_vars) 
dt_id_year_and_type
#>    id year type  na_ratio
#> 1:  1 2002    A 0.5000000
#> 2:  2 2008    B 0.0000000
#> 3:  3 2010    A 0.3333333
#> 4:  3 2010    D 0.3333333
#> 5:  3 2013 <NA> 1.0000000
#> 6:  4 2020    C 0.5000000
#> 7:  5 2009    A 0.0000000
#> 8:  6 2010    B 0.5000000
#> 9:  6 2012 <NA> 1.0000000

# keep only the last observation of each group
dt_unique <- unique(dt_id_year_and_type, by = grouping_vars, fromLast = TRUE)

remove no longer needed helper column
dt_unique[, na_ratio := NULL]
dt_unique
#>    id year type
#> 1:  1 2002    A
#> 2:  2 2008    B
#> 3:  3 2010    D
#> 4:  3 2013 <NA>
#> 5:  4 2020    C
#> 6:  5 2009    A
#> 7:  6 2010    B
#> 8:  6 2012 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse) 

df_id_year_and_type %>% 
  group_by(id, year) %>% 
  fill(type, .direction = "downup") %>% 
  summarise(type = last(type), .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>      id  year type 
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1  2002 A    
#> 2     2  2008 B    
#> 3     3  2010 D    
#> 4     3  2013 <NA> 
#> 5     4  2020 C    
#> 6     5  2009 A    
#> 7     6  2010 B    
#> 8     6  2012 <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
```

A simple, easy to read example of the basic case is

```
df_id_and_type %>% filter(!is.na(type)) %>%  
                   filter(id != lead(id) | id == max(id))
```

extending to the second criteria

```
df_id_year_and_type %>% filter(!is.na(type)) %>%  
                        filter((id != lead(id) | id == max(id)) & 
                                (year != lead(year) | year == max(year)))
```

It is clear and easy to understand.  If you wish to retain the distinct groupings with no result  you can either merge distinct back or insert another OR clause in the filters

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a simple max ?

```
setDT(df_id_year_and_type)
df_id_year_and_type[,max(type, na.rm=T), by=.(id, year)]
```

You will get a warning when there is only NA and the option na.rm is TRUE, but you can suppress it easily:

```
df_id_year_and_type[,suppressWarnings(max(type, na.rm=T)), by=.(id, year)]
```

Or alternatively, test if all values are NA:

```
df_id_year_and_type[,ifelse(all(is.na(type)), NA_character_, max(type, na.rm=T)), by=.(id, year)]
```