# Removing all rows under a specified row in a time series

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to analyze game data but I need to remove of all rows after a specified row.

In the following case I want to remove all rows after the EVENT "Die" for each users. Data is sorted by UID, TIME.HOUR.

df:

```
 UID  TIME.HOUR  EVENT
  1      5       Run
  1      5       Run
  1      6       Run
  1      7       Die
  1      8       Run
  1      9       Run
  2      14      Jump
  2      15      Die
  2      16      Run
  2      17      Run
```

Expected result:

```
 UID  TIME.HOUR  EVENT
  1      5       Run
  1      5       Run
  1      6       Run
  1      7       Die
  2      14      Jump
  2      15      Die
```

I think i'm on the right track with the code below but don't struggling with the next step.

```
 args <- which(df$EVENT== "Die")
 df[,c(sapply(args, function(x) ???), by = UID] #seq? range?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by 'UID', get a double `cumsum` of logical vector (`EVENT == "Die"`), check whether it is less than 2 to Subset the Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[cumsum(cumsum(EVENT=="Die"))<2] , UID]
#   UID TIME.HOUR EVENT
#1:   1         5   Run
#2:   1         5   Run
#3:   1         6   Run
#4:   1         7   Die
#5:   2        14  Jump
#6:   2        15   Die
```

[Or a faster approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/): to get the row index, extract that column (`$V1`) to subset the data

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[cumsum(cumsum(EVENT=="Die"))<2] , UID]$V1]
```

Or a modification of @Psidom's approach

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[seq(match("Die", EVENT, nomatch = .N))] , UID]$V1]
```

---

Or use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(UID) %>% 
   slice(seq(match("Die", EVENT, nomatch = n())))
#    UID TIME.HOUR EVENT
#  <int>     <int> <chr>
#1     1         5   Run
#2     1         5   Run
#3     1         6   Run
#4     1         7   Die
#5     2        14  Jump
#6     2        15   Die
```

In case, we need a `data.frame` output, chain with `%>% as.data.frame` (from @R.S. comments)

Comment: This about `dplyr` part-- That's nifty, and quite flexible. The` slice` part needs `seq` because it will otherwise return only the matching row. Did I get it right? And `nomatch=n()` means go till end in case of no match? BTW, maybe you can also suggest adding `%>% ungroup() %>% as.data.frame() ` at the end to get a cleaned up dataframe .

Comment: @R.S.  You are right, it will only get the matching row if you don't use the `seq`, and `nomatch = n()` is for special cases where there are no matches for a particular UID.  Some people prefer to have their output as `tbl_df`.  So, I will leave it as that and add your comments

Comment: Ah. Thanks. The insight helps.

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't so efficient, but you could do a fancy join:

```
mdf = df[EVENT == "Die", head(.SD, 1L), by=UID, .SDcols = "TIME.HOUR"]
df[!mdf, on=.(UID, TIME.HOUR > TIME.HOUR)]

   UID TIME.HOUR EVENT
1:   1         5   Run
2:   1         5   Run
3:   1         6   Run
4:   1         7   Die
5:   2        14  Jump
6:   2        15   Die
```

You don't actually need to save the `mdf` table as a separate object, of course.

---

*How it works*

- `x[!i]`, where `i` is another data.table or list of vectors, is an anti-join, telling R to exclude rows of `x` based on `i`, similar to how it works with vectors (where `i` would have to be a logical vector).
- The `on=.(ID, v >= v)` option tells R that we're doing a "non-equi join." The `v >= v` part means that the `v` from `i` (on the left-hand side) should be greater than the `v` from `x` (on the right-hand side).

Combining these two, we're excluding rows that meet the criteria specified in the `on=`.

---

*Side notes.* There are a couple things I'm not sure about: Do we have a better name than non-equi join? Why is the `v` on the left from `i` even though `x[i]` has `x` to the left of `i`?

I borrowed from both Psidom and akrun's answer, using `head` and an inequality. One (maybe?) advantage here is that `head(.SD, 1L)` [is optimized](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/523) while `head(.SD, expr)` is not yet.

Comment: Good use of non-equi joins

Answer (score 2):

Another option, you can use `head()` with `match()`(find the first `Die` index):

```
dt[, head(.SD, match("Die", EVENT, nomatch = .N)), UID]   # if no match is found within the 
                                                          # group, return the whole group

#   UID TIME.HOUR EVENT
#1:   1         5   Run
#2:   1         5   Run
#3:   1         6   Run
#4:   1         7   Die
#5:   2        14  Jump
#6:   2        15   Die
```