# Subset by group with data.table compared to aggregate a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is a follow up question to [Subset by group with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table/16574176#16574176) using the same data.table:

```
library(data.table)

bdt <- as.data.table(baseball)

# Aggregating and loosing information on other columns
dt1 <- bdt[ , .(max_g = max(g)), by = id]
# Aggregating and keeping information on other columns
dt2 <- bdt[bdt[, .I[g == max(g)], by = id]$V1]
```

Why do `dt1` and `dt2` differ in number of rows?
Isn't dt2 supposed to have the same result just without loosing the respective information in the other columns?

Comment: Look at, for example, `bdt[id == "woodge01"][order(-g)]` -- that id has multiple rows that maximize `g`. The second approach identifies all such rows, while the first simply returns the maximizing value. This is the difference between max (a value) and argmax (a set of maximizers): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/312012/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This perfectly clarifies the difference!

Comment: Cool, you can post an answer yourself if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Frank pointed out:

`bdt[ , .(max_g = max(g)), by = id]` provides you with the maximum value, while

`bdt[bdt[ , .I[g == max(g)], by = id]$V1]` identifies all rows that have this maximum.

See [What is the difference between *arg max* and *max*?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312012/what-is-the-difference-between-arg-max-and-max) for a mathematical explanation and try this slim version in R:

```
library(data.table)
bdt <- as.data.table(baseball)

dt <- bdt[id == "woodge01"][order(-g)]
dt[ , .(max = max(g)), by = id]
dt[ dt[ , .I[g == max(g)], by = id]$V1 ]
```