# Get all rows fulfilling a condition by group with R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Say we have this toy data.table

```
prueba  <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4), kk=c("FA", "N","N","N",NA,"FA","N", "FA", "N"), rrr=1:9)

id kk rrr
1 FA   1
1  N   2
1  N   3
1  N   4
2 NA   5
2 FA   6
3  N   7
3 FA   8
4  N   9
```

And we want to retrieve all rows pertaining of a given "id" if that id contains any "FA" value on the kk column.

I've got to do it in this way:

```
prueba[id %in% prueba[,any(kk=="FA", na.rm=T),
   by=id]$id[prueba[,any(kk=="FA", na.rm=T),by=id]$V1],]

id kk rrr
1 FA   1
1  N   2
1  N   3
1  N   4
2 NA   5
2 FA   6
3  N   7
3 FA   8
```

(We get all rows with id=1,2 and 3).

But I think it's too long and not optimized.

How would you do it easily with data.table?

Comment: With a join, you could do `prueba[prueba[kk == "FA", .(id)], on="id"]` or use `unique` if there are multiple instances of FA per ID: `prueba[unique(prueba[kk == "FA", .(id)]), on="id"]`.

Comment: you can also use `prueba[, if(any(kk == "FA")) .SD, by= id]`

Comment: Also `prueba[id %in% unique(prueba[kk == "FA", id])]` will work.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I find your solution is the simplest one. If you post it as an answer I will select it.

Comment: @skan, please feel free to post it yourself, perhaps together with other suggestions in comments

Comment: this question is a special case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table/16574176

Comment: @eddi how would you adapt that solution here? prueba[id %in% prueba[, .I[kk == "FA"], by = id]$id,] ?

Comment: `prueba[, .SD[any(kk == 'FA')], by = id]` or `prueba[prueba[, .I[any(kk == 'FA')], by = id]$V1]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about optimized, but cleaned up and using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
prueba %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter('FA'%in%kk)

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
     id    kk   rrr
  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1     1    FA     1
2     1     N     2
3     1     N     3
4     1     N     4
5     2  <NA>     5
6     2    FA     6
7     3     N     7
8     3    FA     8
```

Comment: `dplyr::flter` should be pretty fast in my experience

Comment: I assume it should be fast. But I never get into the speed/optimization conversations as my data almost never requires that focus. So I'm not going to make an argument that I can't back up.

Comment: question was about `data.table`, not `dplyr`

Comment: Yeah, I missed that somehow. I mean, I noticed data.table had been used to build and mutate the data, but I didn't notice the tag or it in the title. And I've had plenty of coffee. I suppose I'll just delete this then.

Answer (score 1):

For a data.table case I would simplify your code to:

```
prueba  <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4), kk=c("FA", "N","N","N",NA,"FA","N", "FA", "N"), rrr=1:9)  

prueba[id %in% unique(prueba[kk=="FA",id])]
```

The output is:

```
   id kk rrr
1:  1 FA   1
2:  1  N   2
3:  1  N   3
4:  1  N   4
5:  2 NA   5
6:  2 FA   6
7:  3  N   7
8:  3 FA   8
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying the different solutions with microbenchmark:

```
prueba  <- data.table(id=rep(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4),1000000), kk=rep(c("FA", "N","N","N",NA,"FA","N", "FA", "N"),1000000), rrr=rep(1:9),1000000)

prueba[, if(any(kk == "FA")) .SD, by= id]               # docendo
prueba[id %in% unique(prueba[kk == "FA", id])]          # lmo
prueba[id %in% prueba[, .I[kk == "FA"], by = id]$id,]   # eddi
prueba[id %in% prueba[,any(kk=="FA", na.rm=T),by=id]
   $id[prueba[,any(kk=="FA", na.rm=T),by=id]$V1],]      # skan
prueba %>%   group_by(id) %>%   filter('FA'%in%kk)      # Andrew
prueba[prueba[kk == "FA", .(id)], on="id"]              # lmo
```

.

```
min       lq       mean     median       uq     max    name
2.206436 2.211022 2.258038 2.215607 2.283839 2.352071   docendo
1.456590 1.472334 1.596654 1.488077 1.666687 1.845296   lmo
2.767113 2.869260 2.953024 2.971408 3.045980 3.120552   eddi
3.431671 3.437914 3.451760 3.444157 3.461804 3.479451   skan
2.088516 2.247807 2.313196 2.407098 2.425535 2.443973   Andrew
```

The last solution by lmo doesn't work, it says:

> Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin ||
>   !anyDuplicated(f__,  :    Join results in more than 2^31 rows
>   (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified
>   join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the
>   same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to
>   run j for each group to avoid the large allocation.

I expected to see a much bigger difference between methods. Maybe with a different dataset.
The fastest method so far seems to be:

```
prueba[id %in% unique(prueba[kk == "FA", id])]
```

I guess there must be better options using .I, .GRP or such functions.