# Calculating convex hull for each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a following data set:

```
structure(list(time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
x = c(40.8914337158203, 20.0796813964844, 13.9093618392944, 
17.1513957977295, 18.5109558105469, 40.7868537902832, 19.9750995635986, 
13.804780960083, 16.8376483917236, 18.4063758850098, 40.6822700500488, 
19.7659358978271, 13.7001991271973, 16.6284866333008, 18.3017921447754, 
40.5776901245117, 19.66135597229, 13.5956182479858, 16.3147411346436, 
18.1972122192383, 40.5776901245117, 19.5567722320557, 13.4910354614258, 
16.1055774688721, 17.9880485534668), y = c(0.603550314903259, 
-8.24852085113525, 9.65680503845215, -19.0118350982666, 6.43787002563477, 
0.704141974449158, -8.34911251068115, 9.75739574432373, -19.2130165100098, 
6.43787002563477, 0.704141974449158, -8.44970417022705, 9.75739574432373, 
-19.5147914886475, 6.43787002563477, 0.704141974449158, -8.65088748931885, 
9.85798835754395, -19.8165683746338, 6.33727836608887, 0.704141974449158, 
-8.85207080841064, 9.85798835754395, -20.1183433532715, 6.33727836608887
), object = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), .Names = c("time", 
"x", "y", "object"))
```

Now, I would like to calculate a convex hull (using `chull` function) for each value of `time` and store it within the same dataset (as I would like to make a plot with `ggplot2` then). 
I can use `chull` for each time value using with

```
chull(filter(data_sample, time == 1)$x, filter(data_sample, time == 1)$y)
```

which returns a vector of `4 3 1`. So I thought that I can group by time firstly and calculate convex hull points within groups with something like

```
data_sample %>% group_by(time) %>% summarise(pts = chull(data_sample$x, data_sample$y))
```

The problem is that I cannot store a vector in a row. Storing each of vertices in separate column would be an option, but the following

```
data_sample %>% group_by(time) %>% summarise(pt1 = chull(data_sample$x, data_sample$y)[1])
```

doesn't give reasonable results. So my questions are:
1. How can I store a vector for each row within one column? I have read that tibbles can actually have a list column, but how can I create that in my case?
2. What's wrong with my attempt to calculate `chull` within each group?

- (extra question, if I may) Why actually `data_sample %>% filter(time == 1) %>% chull(.$x, .$y)` doesn't work? Is this because `chull` is not design to work with pipes and `dplyr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `chull` is giving you indices on the original data, you probably want to preserve the coordinates as you go, which means you probably should not be using `summarize`. I suggest you go with the "nested" concept as done with `tidyr`. The first step is nesting your data:

```
library(tidyr)
data_sample %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  nest()
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#    time             data
#   <int>           <list>
# 1     1 <tibble [5 × 3]>
# 2     2 <tibble [5 × 3]>
# 3     3 <tibble [5 × 3]>
# 4     4 <tibble [5 × 3]>
# 5     5 <tibble [5 × 3]>
```

From here, it's just a matter of calculating the hull (which will return a vector of indices) and then output the relevant rows, in the order provided. This will benefit from the `map` functions provided by `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
data_sample %>%    data_sample %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    hull = map(data, ~ with(.x, chull(x, y))),
    out = map2(data, hull, ~ .x[.y,,drop=FALSE])
  )
# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#    time             data      hull              out
#   <int>           <list>    <list>           <list>
# 1     1 <tibble [5 × 3]> <int [3]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
# 2     2 <tibble [5 × 3]> <int [3]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
# 3     3 <tibble [5 × 3]> <int [3]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
# 4     4 <tibble [5 × 3]> <int [3]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
# 5     5 <tibble [5 × 3]> <int [3]> <tibble [3 × 3]>
```

(You should be able to get away with putting both assignments into a single `mutate`. I

From here, you can turn it into the coordinates you need by removing now-unnecessary columns and unnesting:

```
data_sample %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    hull = map(data, ~ with(.x, chull(x, y))),
    out = map2(data, hull, ~ .x[.y,,drop=FALSE])
  ) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest()
# # A tibble: 15 × 5
#     time  hull        x           y object
#    <int> <int>    <dbl>       <dbl>  <int>
# 1      1     4 17.15140 -19.0118351      4
# 2      1     3 13.90936   9.6568050      3
# 3      1     1 40.89143   0.6035503      1
# 4      2     4 16.83765 -19.2130165      4
# 5      2     3 13.80478   9.7573957      3
# 6      2     1 40.78685   0.7041420      1
# 7      3     4 16.62849 -19.5147915      4
# 8      3     3 13.70020   9.7573957      3
# 9      3     1 40.68227   0.7041420      1
# 10     4     4 16.31474 -19.8165684      4
# 11     4     3 13.59562   9.8579884      3
# 12     4     1 40.57769   0.7041420      1
# 13     5     4 16.10558 -20.1183434      4
# 14     5     3 13.49104   9.8579884      3
# 15     5     1 40.57769   0.7041420      1
```

(I kept `hull` here for demonstration purposes; you probably can `select(-data, -hull)` above since you'll have what you need, especially if redundant with `object`.)

For your last question, you could have done either one of these:

```
filter(data_sample, time == 1) %>%
  with(., chull(x, y))
with(filter(data_sample, time == 1), chull(x, y))
```

Comment: Wow, exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass chull function inside a list:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(chull_val = list(chull(x,y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to work with list columns*, you may consider using (the more flexible) `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[d[ , .I[chull(x, y)], by = time]$V1]
```

Explanation: convert your data to a `data.table` (`setDT(d)`). For each time (`by = time`), calculate the `chull` indices and select the corresponding rows (`.I`) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table)).

---

If you want to plot the `chull` polygons, you need to add the first index to close the polygon.

```
d2 <- d[ , {

  # for each time (by = time):
  # compute the indices lying on the convex hull  
  ix <- chull(x, y)

  # use indices to select data of each subset (.SD)
  # possibly also add the first coordinate to close the polygon for plotting   
  .SD[c(ix, ix[1])]}, by = time]


# plot chull and original polygons
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(d2, aes(x, y, fill = factor(time))) +
  geom_polygon(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_polygon(data = d, alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

---

*Related `dplyr` issues: [Summarising verbs with variable-length outputs](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2132), [Optional parameter to control length of summarise](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/154).