# Calculations based on a dynamic subgroup of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My question is related to [Subset by group with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table) but different.

Imagine a data set like this:

```
tmp <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = c(27, 70, 54, 18, 50, 44, 22, 73, 6, 5))
```

For each row of the data, I want to calculate a new value, z, which is the `min(y)` for all rows with a larger value of x. For instance, for the third row of the data where x is 3, I want `min(y)` among rows with x > 3 (which would be the value 5). For our intents and purposes, you can assume the data is already ordered by x.

At first I thought of using a function like this:

```
min.y <- function(val, dt) {
  dt[x > val, min(y)]
}
```

But calling `tmp[, z:= fun(x, tmp)]` will result in a warning message:

```
In min(y) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

What is the proper way to do this?

PS: Obviously, for the last row I expect to get NA as the result

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1:**

Since you said we can assume the data is sorted on `x` you could use a cumulative minimum starting from the end of `y`. We cut out the first observation so that we do a `>` search rather than `>=`:

```
tmp$min_y <- c(rev(cummin(rev(tmp$y[-1]))), NA)
```

*Update*: The old method effectively did a `>=` search rather than `>`. Updated to do `>`.

---

**Method 2: Data.table**

If you wanted to use `data.table` you could try to group by each row and then subset within `J`. The ifelse is needed so that when we are at our last row we don't take the min of no values:

```
tmp[, "min_y" := {curr_x <- x
                  tmp_subs <- tmp[x > curr_x]
                  ifelse(nrow(tmp_subs)>0, min(tmp[x > curr_x][["y"]]), NA_real_)},
    by = 1:nrow(tmp)]

tmp
#     x  y min_y
# 1:  1 27     5
# 2:  2 70     5
# 3:  3 54     5
# 4:  4 18     5
# 5:  5 50     5
# 6:  6 44     5
# 7:  7 22     5
# 8:  8 73     5
# 9:  9  6     5
#10: 10  5     NA
```

Since `5` is the smallest value which is at the end everything will be `5`. Let's make this a little more interesting:

```
tmp <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = c(27, 70, 54, 18, 50, 44, 22, 73, 47, 58))
```

Our result will be:

```
#     x  y min_y
# 1:  1 27    18
# 2:  2 70    18
# 3:  3 54    18
# 4:  4 18    22
# 5:  5 50    22
# 6:  6 44    22
# 7:  7 22    47
# 8:  8 73    47
# 9:  9 47    58
#10: 10 58    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be a self-non-equi join

```
tmp[, min_y := .SD[.SD, min(y, na.rm = TRUE), on = .(x > x),
         by = .EACHI]$V1][is.infinite(min_y), min_y := NA_real_][]
#      x  y min_y
# 1:  1 27     5
# 2:  2 70     5
# 3:  3 54     5
# 4:  4 18     5
# 5:  5 50     5
# 6:  6 44     5
# 7:  7 22     5
# 8:  8 73     5
# 9:  9  6     5
#10: 10  5    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth, one more possible approach (not sure if its any better or worse than the others):

```
tmp[, z := min(tmp$y[(.I+1):NROW(tmp)]), by = 1:NROW(tmp)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions:

**1) rollapply** Assuming `tmp` is sorted (sort it if not), we can use `rollapply` to get a compact solution like this.  Note that when the `width` argument of `rollapply` is a list its elements are regarded as vectors of offsets over which to apply `min`.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

tmp[, min := rollapply(y, lapply(pmax(.N:1-1, 1), seq), min, fill = NA)]
```

giving:

```
     x  y min
 1:  1 27   5
 2:  2 70   5
 3:  3 54   5
 4:  4 18   5
 5:  5 50   5
 6:  6 44   5
 7:  7 22   5
 8:  8 73   5
 9:  9  6   5
10: 10  5  NA
```

**2) sqldf**  Using SQL join `tmp` to itself using the indicated condition and take the min over the group like this.  `tmp` need not be sorted.

```
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, min(b.y) min 
       from tmp a left join tmp b on b.x > a.x group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
    x  y min
1   1 27   5
2   2 70   5
3   3 54   5
4   4 18   5
5   5 50   5
6   6 44   5
7   7 22   5
8   8 73   5
9   9  6   5
10 10  5  NA
```