# Obtain quickly the rows with maximal value for each indicator in a big data.table

Tags: r, filter, data.table

I am given a large data.table, e.g.

```
n <- 7
dt <- data.table(id_1=sample(1:10^(n-1),10^n,replace=TRUE), other=sample(letters[1:20],10^n,replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(10^n,mean=10^4,sd=1000))

> structure(dt)
        id_1 other       val

    1: 914718     o  9623.078  
    2: 695164     f 10323.943
    3:  53186     h 10930.825
    4: 496575     p  9964.064
    5: 474733     l 10759.779
   ---                       
9999996: 650001     p  9653.125
9999997: 225775     i  8945.636
9999998: 372827     d  8947.095
9999999: 268678     e  8371.433
10000000: 730810     i 10150.311
```

and I would like to create a data.table that for each value of the indicator `id_1` only has one row, namely the one with the largest value in the column `val`.

The following code seems to work:

```
dt[, .SD[which.max(val)], by = .(id_1)]
```

However, it is very slow for large tables.
Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/5793905),
but the answer wasn't really explained,
so here it goes:

```
dt[dt[, .(which_max = .I[val == max(val)]), by = "id_1"]$which_max]
```

The inner expression basically finds,
for each group according to `id_1`,
the row index of the max value,
and simply returns those indices so that they can be used to subset `dt`.

However, I'm kind of surprised I didn't find an answer suggesting this:

```
setkey(dt, id_1, val)[, .SD[.N], by = "id_1"]
```

which seems to be similarly fast in my machine,
but it requires the rows to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it in R, but what I have done is read line by line and then put those lines into data frame. This is very fast and happens in a flash for a 100 mb text file.

```
import pandas as pd
filename ="C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/123456789.012-01-433.txt"
filename =filename

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    sample =[]          #creating an empty array
    for line in f:
        tag=line[:45].split('|')[5] # its a condition, you dont need this.
        if tag == 'KV-C901':
            sample.append(line.split('|')) # writing those lines to an array table

print('arrays are appended and ready to create a dataframe out of an array')
```