# data.table performance using .SD with by

Tags: r, data.table, microbenchmark

I want to filter a large `data.table` by group. I can use `.SD` or `.I` and while I personally think the former is much easier to read, the latter is tremendously faster / uses much less memory (despite using `.SDcols`).

To some extent it is clear to me why. For `.I` we just need a vector per group, while for `.SD` we need a whole `data.table`. But I thought that by providing a meaningful `.SDcol` argument I could speed up / save some memory.

However, the benchmarks show that the `.SD` approach is about 60 times slower and eats up 300 times more memory. Granted, a 4 column `.SD` data.table will need more than 4 times the size of a vector. But 60 times slower and 300 times more memory? Could somebody enlighten me, why the `.SD` approach eats up so much memory and is thus so much slower? Is there a way how I could speed up the `.SD` approach to be faster or is the only option to fall back to the `.I` approach?

**Data Setup**

```r
library(data.table)
## data set up

nr <- 1e6
nc <- 100
grp_perc <- .8
DT <- data.table(ids = sample(paste0("id", 
                                     seq(1, round(grp_perc * nr, 0))),
                              nr, TRUE))
cols <- paste("col", seq(1, nc), sep = "_")
DT[, (cols) := replicate(nc, sample(nr), simplify = FALSE)]
```

**Benchmarks**

```r
results <- bench::mark(.I = DT[DT[, .(row_id = .I[which.min(col_1)]), 
                                  by = ids]$row_id, c("ids", cols[1:3]), with = FALSE],
                       .SD = DT[, .SD[which.min(col_1)], 
                                by = ids, .SDcols = cols[1:3]], 
                       iterations = 1, filter_gc = FALSE)

summary(results)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 13
>   expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result         memory         time   gc       
>   <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>         <list>         <list> <list>   
> 1 .I           2.64s   2.64s   0.378      34.4MB    0         1     0      2.64s <df[,4] [571,~ <df[,3] [1,41~ <bch:~ <tibble ~
> 2 .SD          2.73m   2.73m   0.00612     9.1GB    0.342     1    56      2.73m <df[,4] [571,~ <df[,3] [2,40~ <bch:~ <tibble ~
> ```

Comment: My understanding is that the .SD approach is slower because it results in multiple method dispatches of `[.data.table`. See this [Github issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574176/13095326).

Comment: Very insightful. Thanks, this explains the issue very well and I think for similar issues I will look mor on the verbose mode to learn more about the internals of `data.table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach that is faster than the `.I` for this particular example. Note that this also changes the order which may not be desirable for you.

```
DT[order(col_1), .SD[1L], by = ids, .SDcols = cols[1:3]]
```

As @Ian Campbell mentions, this is a Github issue. The good news is that there are some optimizations, one of which being `.SD[1L]`. The optimization is that the subsetting is done all in C which makes it very fast.

Here are the benchmarks which includes @sindri_baldur's solution but removes your original `.SD` attempt - I didn't want to wait 3 minutes :).

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression    min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 .I          4.54s  4.54s    0.220       30MB    0.880     1     4      4.54s
2 self_join  11.32s 11.32s    0.0883    76.3MB    0         1     0     11.32s
3 use_order   3.55s  3.55s    0.282     58.3MB    0         1     0      3.55s

## show that it's equal but re-ordered:
all.equal(DT[DT[, .(row_id = .I[which.min(col_1)]), 
                by = ids]$row_id, c("ids", cols[1:3]), with = FALSE][order(col_1)],
          DT[order(col_1), .SD[1L], by = ids, .SDcols = cols[1:3]])

## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Beautiful! However, you need quite some deep understanding of the internals of `data.table` to understand that `.SD[which.min(col_1)]` is so much slower than `.SD[1L]`, but the link posted by @[Ian Campbell]  makes that quite clear.

Comment: And I think your concern about the order is unnecessary, since I am anyways aggregating the data - so the original order is meaningless on the aggregated table.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a faster way that still uses .SD.

```r
DT[DT[, .(col_1 = min(col_1)), by = ids], 
   on = .(ids, col_1), 
   .SD, .SDcols = c("ids", cols[1:3])]
```

Comment: Not an expert but experience tells me its best to keep things simple and rely on optimised functions when using `by`.

Comment: Thanks +1. I am far to little accustomed to using (self) joins and should definitely use them more often.