# Subset by aggregate value with data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

Say I'm grouping a data.table by a certain column and counting the values per group. Then I want to remove the groups that have count `N < 2`. Is there an efficient, data.table way to do this?

Example data:

```
id | col1
-------------
1  | "A"
2  | "A"
3  | "B"
4  | "C"
5  | "C"
```

now: group by `col1` and count, remove rows that belong to group with `count < 2`

Example output: (row `3` was removed)

```
id | col1
-------------
1  | "A"
2  | "A"
4  | "C"
5  | "C"
```

I found [Subset by group with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table) which is sort of similar, but I don't want to find a specific row per group, but rather identify entire groups if their aggregate satisfies a certain condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
values_2_keep <- DT[, .N, by = col1][N>=2, col1] 
# Alternatively DT[rowid(col1)==2L, col1]

DT[col1 %in% values_2_keep]

   id col1
1:  1    A
2:  2    A
3:  4    C
4:  5    C
```

Reproducible data:

```
DT <- data.table(
  id = 1:5,
  col1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C")
)
```