# Why is filtering by groups bigger than x observations taking longer in data.table than in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to filter groups with more than 20 observations per group in my dataset (8.5M rows). I intend to translate most of my code from `dplyr` to `data.table` for the sake of efficiency.
This is the operation I have chosen for `data.table` (I am not too familiar with the syntax yet so there may probably be a better way to write it):

```
df <- df[, .SD[.N > 20], by = cols]
```

And this is the equivalent in `dplyr` that I was using previously:

```r
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(across(all_of(cols))) %>%
  filter(n() > 20) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The `data.table` option is taking 7 times more than the `dplyr` one, even though the df was a data.table already before any of the operations.

Why does this happen and how could I rewrite the code of `data.table` to make it faster?

Comment: Try `df[, .N, by = cols][N > 20]`

Comment: As for why, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-rows-corresponding-to-max-value-by-group-using-data-table)

Comment: @Jamie, the operation is fast, but it doesn't produce the output I wanted. The final data.table only has the columns specified in `cols` and N. I would simply want to take out those groups and come back to my original table, as in the first code snippet of the question.